# N-dimensional N^N array filled with N

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, generation, data-structures

**In:** Enough memory and a positive integer N

**Out:** N-dimensional N^N array filled with N, where N^N means N terms of N-by-N-by-N-by...

**Examples:**

1: `[1]` which is a 1D array (a list) of length 1, containing a single 1

2: `[[2,2],[2,2]]` which is a 2D array (a table) with 2 rows and 2 columns, filled with 2s

3: `[[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]]` which is a 3D array (a cube) with 3 layers, 3 rows, and 3 columns, filled with 3s

4: `[[[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]],[[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]],[[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]],[[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]],[[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]]]`

5 and 6: Please see one of the answers.

Comment: If our language does not support arrays, what would be an acceptable output format?

Comment: @Okx JSON, or any other unambiguous array notation.

Comment: Since "Enough memory" is part of the input, I want to see an answer that controls a robot to actually take the memory as input and plug it in before using it.

Comment: Do all the arrays need to be distinct objects?

Comment: @user2357112 I think that's more of a precondition type issue. I doubt the op actually expects the function to accept memory as input.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Correct, but I'm pretty sure user2357112 meant it as a joke.

Comment: @Neil I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take the case N = 3. Am I allowed to write (unrolled) `a = 3; a = [a, a, a]; a = [a, a, a]; a = [a, a, a];` or must I write `a11 = [3, 3, 3]; a12 = [3, 3, 3]; a13 = [3, 3, 3]; a1 = [a11, a12, a13]; /* etc. for a2 and a3 */ a = [a1, a2, a3];`?

Comment: @Neil Ah, they are pointers, so the if one sets the very first element of the first a to 2, all the elements of a become 2, whereas that isn't the case for the second a. The first is fine too, if it isn't too much work, I'd be interested in seeing both for comparison.

Comment: 5. and 6. seem expired.

Comment: @sergiol Now that there are plenty of answers, you can just use one of the Try it Online! links to generate the desired outputs.

Comment: can I have a trailing comma at the end of the answer like "[1]," or "[[2,2],[2,2]],"

Comment: @JoshM You're supposed to return/output an array.

Comment: @Adám nvm I figured it out

Comment: The hastebin links seem to be broken. They redirect me to the main site

Answer (score 57):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval('['*n+'n'+']*n'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5ValpijoR6trpWnrZ6nrq0eq5UHZGv@T8svUkhWyMxTMNQx0jG24uIsKMrMK1FI00jW/A8A)

Makes a string like `"[[[n]*n]*n]*n"` with `n` multiplcations, and evaluates it as Python code. Since the evaluation happens within the function scope, the variable name `n` evaluates to the function input.

Comment: the scope trick is genius

Comment: +1, that eval trick really golfs down a lot of bytes

Answer (score 34):

## J, 4 bytes

```
$~#~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloFKnXMfFlZqcka@QpmD8/z8A)

### Explanation

```
$~#~  Input: integer n
  #~  Create n copies of n
$~    Shape n into an array with dimensions n copies of n
```

Comment: When I saw the challenge title, I thought of J immediately. Pretty cool that J even beats Jelly (the golfing language inspired by J).

Comment: There's also `$~$~` which is equivalent while also repeating itself

Comment: `$~$~` translated to English... MONEY, get more of, MONEY, get more of...

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

```apl
⍴⍨⍴⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@5@m8KhtgsKj3i2PeleAyK5FXFyP@qaCRdMUDJHYRkhsYyS2yf//AA)

Comment: Btw, [`⍴⍨⍴⍨`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P03hUdsEhUe9Wx71roCQXFyP@qaCRdMUDJHYRkhsYyS2yf//AA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") works too, while looking cooler.

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
(t=Table)@@t[#,#+1]&

(* or *)

Table@@Table[#,#+1]&
```

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6),  <s>44</s>  40 bytes

```js
f=(n,k=i=n)=>i--?f(n,Array(n).fill(k)):k
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k=i=n)=>i--?f(n,Array(n).fill(k)):k

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4)))
```

Answer (score 10):

## Octave, <s>35</s> <s>33</s> <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
@(N)ones(N+!(1:N))*N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@g4aeZn5darOGnrahhaOWnqanl9z8xr1jDWPM/AA)

```
@(N)ones(N*ones(1,N))*N

@(N)repmat(N,N*ones(1,N))
```

Thanks to @LuisMendo saved 8 bytes

```
@(N)ones(num2cell(!(1:N)+N){:})*N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@g4aeZn5darJFXmmuUnJqTo6GoYWjlp6ntp1ltVaup5fc/Ma9Yw1jzPwA)

Previous answer:

```
@(N)repmat(N,num2cell(!(1:N)+N){:})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@g4adZlFqQm1ii4aeTV5prlJyak6OhqGFo5aep7adZbVWr@T8xr1jDWPM/AA)

Comment: @LuisMendo Rats, I was just going to post that one ;)

Comment: @beaker Whoops :-)

Answer (score 10):

## R, 26

This is the obvious answer but perhaps there is something cleverer?

```
n=scan();array(n,rep(n,n))
```

Comment: is `scan()` necessary?

Comment: Looking at the other answers, it seems like it either has to be a function or accept input somehow?

Comment: Right, I don't know R at all. I just thought that you could specify a function somehow instead.

Comment: Yes, you can replace `n=scan();` by `function(n)` but it makes it longer.

Comment: can it be `scan()%>%array(rep(.,.))`? It uses `magrittr` operator

Comment: pryr::f(array(n,rep(n,n))) creates an unnamed function instead of using scan, but doesn't save any bytes.

Comment: You can save one byte by putting the `n` assignment inside of `array`: `array(n<-scan(),rep(n,n))`.

Comment: @raymkchow `library(magrittr)` adds quite a few bytes.

Comment: I've always wondered why R coders in this section don't just use a variable name instead of scan, as other do with their languages.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

-1 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
F¹.D)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7dBOPRfN//@NAQ)

```
F     # For 0 .. input
 ¹.D) # Push <input> copies of the result of the last step as an array
```

Comment: The leading `D` can be removed because the input is used implicitly again (not sure if this was a thing when you posted the answer, but you don't need the explicit `D` anymore now).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think this is one of the answers that gave us the idea to take implicitly input multiple times :)

Comment: Ah ok. I was indeed expecting it to not be implicitly yet at the time of posting, but realized that after posting my comment (which I edited). ;) Sometimes it's funny how much explicit things are being done by old answer (usually pre-2017), and how much shorter it can be done now.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

```hs
f n=iterate(filter(>'"').show.(<$[1..n]))(show n)!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FchBCoAgEAXQq3xDcGYzEG2zi0QLKSWhJiih41vuHu8MWeGRtcQ7rAUWCYI7hq0mqM@tS6SUj180uc6xPPv1Co127kV0YaYWUDZGax0@)

Inspired by [@nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111700), but using more predefined functions.

- Uses `iterate` and `!!` instead of a recursive help function.
- Instead of constructing list delimiters "by hand", uses `filter(>'"').show` to format a list of strings, then stripping away the extra `"` characters.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 62 bytes

```
n#0=show n
n#l='[':tail((',':)=<<n#(l-1)<$[1..n])++"]"
f n=n#n
```

Usage example: `f 2` -> `"[[2,2],[2,2]]"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcqxDkAwFAXQ3Ve8qKRt0BCb9P0Bk1E6dBGSuoSKz68480kQDd/r8RIyiMByln30W1BKVrLXbC2ECnWrbTG3xsDpssxdni0EhkDa/QZi2v05kjqfOMVrgFk0/btzlD4).

Haskell's strict type system prevents a function that returns nested lists of different depths, so I construct the result as a string.

How it works:

```
n#l=                         n with the current level l is
    '[':                     a literal [ followed by
           n#(l-1)<$[1..n]   n copies of   n # (l-1)
        (',':)=<<            each prepended by a , and flattened into a single list
      tail                   and the first , removed
                  ++"]"      followed by a literal ]

n#0=show n                   the base case is n as a string

f n=n#n                      main function, start with level n
```

Comment: We can do the same idea shorter with more builtin functions: ``f n=iterate(filter(>'#').show.(<$[1..n]))(show n)!!n``.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: that's a great idea. Please post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Could you shave a byte with `(#0)=show`? Not too familiar with Haskell

Comment: @Cyoce: No, that's a syntax error. For a correct syntax I could flip the arguments and use `(#)0=show`, but all definitions of a function must have the same number of arguments. The second line (`n#l='['...`) needs two arguments, so the first line must also have two arguments.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @CalculatorFeline

```python
a=n=input()
exec"a=[a]*n;"*n
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59om2ebmVdQWqKhyZVakZqslGgbnRirlWetpJX3v6AoM69EI1HzvwkA)

Comment: `~-n`==`(n-1)`.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a [TIO link](https://tio.run/nexus/python2)?

Comment: In fact, [this!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59om2ebmVdQWqKhyZVakZqslGgbnRirlWetpJXHVVCUmVeikaj5/78JAA) (-8 bytes due to optimized algorithm, +9 bytes to add output)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline You can put things in Header and Footer to avoid inclusion in byte count.

Comment: Aren't input and output required in full program submissions?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I only meant to imply the default rules. I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, 8 bytes

```
ttY"l$l*
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=ttY%222%24X%22%0A%0A%27Actual+Size%27yZy++++%25+Display+the+actual+size&inputs=4&version=19.8.0) (I have added some code showing the *actual* size of the output since all n-dimensional outputs in MATL are shown as 2D matrices where all dimensions > 2 are flattened into the second dimension).

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the input (N)
tt      % Make two copies of N
Y"      % Perform run-length decoding to create N copies of N
l$1     % Create a matrix of ones that is this size  
*       % Multiply this matrix of ones by N
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: I can't really tell from MATL Online whether your submission does the right thing. looks like every answer is a wide matrix.

Comment: @Adám Dimensions beyond the second are displayed as collapsed into the second. So the example shows a 3x9 array instead of the produced 3x3x3 array. If you add `Zy` at the end of the code it tells the actual size

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁾Wẋẋv
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocV/4w13dQFT2//9/EwA)**

#### How?

```
⁾Wẋẋv - Main link: n                            e.g.       3
⁾Wẋ   - character pair literal ['W','ẋ']                  "Wẋ"
   ẋ  - repeat list n times                               "WẋWẋWẋ"
    v - evaluate as Jelly code with input n          eval("WẋWẋWẋ", 3)
      - ...
        WẋWẋ... - toEval: n                e.g. 3
        W        - wrap                        [3]
         ẋ       - repeat list n times         [3,3,3]
          Wẋ     - wrap and repeat            [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]
            ...  - n times total             [[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]]
```

Comment: [Second](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111686/43319) 5-byte Jelly answer. Still unacceptably long compared to [J](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111683/43319) :-)

Comment: ...and not for want of trying :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
R»µ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0O5DWw8t/P//vzEA)

```
R»µ¡
R     Range. 2 -> [1, 2]
 »    Max between left arg and right arg. Vectorizes. -> [2, 2]
  µ   Separates into a new chain.
   ¡  Repeat 2 times. After another iteration this yields [[2, 2], [2, 2]].
```

Same thing but with a single monad and no need for the chain separator:

[**4 bytes**](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7kdNaxIOLfz//78xAA)

```
»€`¡
```

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
ri:X{aX*}X*p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaRVRnRihVRuhVfD/vzEA)

**Explanation**

```
ri:X          Read an integer from input, store it in X (leaves it on the stack)
    {   }X*   Execute this block X times:
     a          Wrap the top of stack in an array
      X*        Repeat the array X times
           p  Print nicely
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java <s>97</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```
Object c(int n,int i){Object[]a=new Object[n];for(int j=0;j<n;)a[j++]=i<2?n:c(n,i-1);return a;}
```

---

Ungolfed:

```
public class N_Dim {
    
    public static Object create(int n) {
        return create(n, n);
    }
        
    public static Object create(int n, int i) {
        Object[] array = new Object[n];
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            array[j] = i<2?n:create(n, i - 1);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) create(3)));
    }

}
```

Comment: can you replace `i<=1` with `i<2` ?

Comment: Yes @cliffrott. That worked. thanks!!

Comment: You could save a few bytes with a lambda: `(n,i)->{...}`

Comment: Java 8 lambdas ftw

Comment: Hmm, looks like this takes extra input. You'll need to make a separate method of just one parameter in order for this to be valid.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```
f=(n,m=n)=>m?Array(n).fill(f(n,m-1)):n
```

The memory-hungry version of this is 45 bytes:

```
f=(n,m=n)=>m?[...Array(n)].map(_=>f(n,m-1)):n
```

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 141 bytes

```
@set t=.
@for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do @call set t=%%t%%,.
@set s=%1
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call call set s=[%%%%t:.=%%s%%%%%%]
@echo %s%
```

Batch doesn't actually have arrays so this just prints the string representation of an array. Explanation: The first two lines build up a repeated pattern of `N` `.`s separated by `N-1` `,`s in the variable `t`. The fourth line then uses this as a substitution pattern `N` times to create the `N`-dimensional array. The double `call` is necessary because of how the `for` and `set` statements work. First, the `for` command substitutes variables. As it happens, all of my `%` signs are doubled, so this does nothing except to unquote them all, resulting in `call call set s=[%%t:.=%s%%%]`. It then repeats the resulting statement `N` times. Each time, the `call` command substitutes variables. At this point, the `s` variable only has a single set of `%`s, so it gets substituted, resulting in (e.g.) `call set s=[%t:.=[2,2]%]`. The inner call then substitutes the `t` variable, resulting in (e.g.) `set s=[[2,2],[2,2]]`, performing the desired assignment. The final value of `s` is then printed.

Comment: +1 Wow, I wouldn't have expected that. All hail the humble .bat file!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Wẋ³µ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/@cFf3oc2Hth5a@P//fxMA)

### Explanation

```
         Implicit input: N
   µ¡    Apply N times to input:
Wẋ³        “N copies of”
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>57</s> <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,c=0:n-c and[f(n,c+1)*n]or 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnk2xrYJWnm6yQmJcSnaYB5GsbamrlxeYXKRj@z7PNzCvRyMwrKC3R0NTkKigCcYGKNDX/mwAA)

---

-4 bytes thanks to @CalculatorFeline

---

**34 bytes:**

```python
f=lambda c,n:c and[f(c-1,n)*n]or 1
```

Needs to be called as `f(4,4)`

Comment: Why are your code lines reversed compared to your TIO link?

Comment: You can replace `c>1` with `c `  to save 1 byte. (Markdown, stop deduplicating spaces across `\``s)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I don't think he can; that would `c>0` in this particular case.

Comment: Then change the end to `<space>n`. Problem solved and bonus–more bytes saved! :D (So spaces at the end of inline code is possible, but not the beginning? That's strange...) [TIO link](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7eN@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WmkaeTp8mVZgsVSdbJs0pWSMxLidaKTtNI1jUEysZq5cXmFynk/c@zzcwr0cjMKygt0dDU5CooAnHTNfI0Nf@bAAA)

Comment: @Adám: On TIO to allow the main function to be assigned in the header and here to keep the main function on the last line.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <strike>28</strike> 26  bytes

*Thanks to [Cyoce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41042/cyoce) for saving 2 bytes!*

```
->n{eval'['*n+'n'+']*n'*n}
```

Stolen shamelessly from [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111696/58437).

Comment: Do you need those parens?

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 27 bytes

```
->a{(z=a).times{z=[z]*a};z}
```

Only 1 byte more but using a different approach instead of the 'eval' trick from xnor's wonderful Python answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 117 bytes

```bash
n=$[$1**$1]
seq -f$1o%.fd$n+1-p $n|dc|rev|sed -r "s/(0+|$[$1-1]*).*$/\1/;s/^(0*)/\1$1/;s/^1/[1]/"|tr \\n0$[$1-1] \ []
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#LcsxDoMwDEDRvaewkJHAKDiWulU9SZIuTRhDm6BOvnsKgu3/4bX8RIdChBJuNX3BLChrPy8R8yTmA5g1vrWkn9YUwRToKg920kMZCTTOhOyFH5Vfg6VxbzxP2EngTrcC3md7AfDgQmvt/gc)

---

The program essentially counts from 0 to (n^n)-1 in base n, where n is the input. For each base-n number k in the count, it does the following:

1. If k ends with at least one digit 0, print a '[' for each digit 0 at the end of k.
2. Print n.
3. If k ends with at least one digit n-1, print a ']' for each digit n-1 at the end of k.

(The value n=1 needs to have brackets added as a special case. This input value also generates some output to stderr, which can be ignored under standard PPCG rules.)

Maybe there's a shorter way to implement this idea.

---

Sample run:

```bash
./array 3
[[[3 3 3] [3 3 3] [3 3 3]] [[3 3 3] [3 3 3] [3 3 3]] [[3 3 3] [3 3 3] [3 3 3]]]
```

Comment: My [Zsh solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233813/15940) could probably translate to Bash

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

Other than the existing Haskell solutions this constructs a usable data type not just a string representation thereof (and is shorter):

```hs
data L=N[L]|E Int
f n=iterate(N.(<$[1..n]))(E n)!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCoNAEET7@4oRUniFQiClVsEiIDZJJxZHXHNHzBruNmgg/24UQZiBea8Ya8KT@n6eWyMGZV7VZfMrcGFRHTh3Qt4IxVUaZ4f6mKbcaB0XYB1FPCcJbtYFLBm4/4KJWmrhOoyE0bBABry9W4cleAqfXpTjIIbvhKsdRpQYLXlSQFhx@Z40kG807brCFPSug1Iv43jh7T1Ft9STaZFnGR4k54GFWMJ8@gM)

#### Explanation / Ungolfed

The reason why this is an interesting challenge in Haskell is that a solution to this challenge needs to return different deeply nested lists and Haskell (without importing external modules) does not support this. One workaround which turned out to be the golfiest, is to define our own data type:

```hs
data NestedList = Nest [NestedList] | Entry Int
```

Now we can just define a function `f :: Int -> NestedList` which is able to represent all the required data types:

```hs
pow n = iterate (Nest . replicate n) (Entry n) !! n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
_{a*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z@@OlHr/39DLiMuYy6T/wA)

### Explanation using `n = 2` (note that the outermost `[]` are not arrays, but are just there to show the stack)

```
_      duplicate TOS (stack is [2, 2])
 {     loop 2 times (stack is [2])
  a    wrap in array ([2] => [[2]], [[2, 2]] => [[[2, 2]]])
   *   pop a, b : push(a*b) ([[2]] => [[2, 2]], [[[2, 2]]] => [[[2, 2], [2, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 21 bytes

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/786OrqiIlYBTKjEK1RUKBjH1mqkp5Zo6hUnVv7/bwQA)

```
{[[xx] [xx] $_ xx 3]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```julia
n->n>(n>n)...
> =fill
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y7PTiPPLk9TT0@Py07BNi0zJ@d/bmKBBlBGIyWzuCAnsVIjTSNPU9O6oCgzryQnT0NTU0dBw1DHWMdUU/M/AA)

(Thanks to @MarcMush for -2 bytes.)

In Julia, binary operators are parsed as function calls, so `a>b` is `>(a, b)`, which here is `fill(a, b)`. So the above is really saying:

```julia
n->fill(n,fill(n,n)...)
```

The first argument to `fill` is the value to fill the new array with. The following arguments to that are the dimensions of the new array. Here we create those dimensions themselves using another `fill` call: we create an array of `n` `n`s, then splat that with `...` so that the first `fill`  call gets n number of dimension arguments, each with value n - so it creates an n-dimensional array where each dimension length is n, and filled with the value n.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y7PTiPPLk9TT0@Py07BNi0zJ@d/bmKBBlBGIyWzuCAnsVIjTSNPU9O6oCgzryQnT0NTU0dBw1DHWMdUU/M/AA "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online") I'm surprised this works

Comment: I was wondering why @MarcMush 's improved version doesn't work if we used `+` or `*` instead of `>`, which lead to a [Zulip discussion](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/225542-helpdesk/topic/Binary.20operators.20as.20functions/near/251404434), and a [Github issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/42074) from that. (The answer has to do with precedence btw, of `>` vs `...` vs `+`,`*`,etc.)

Comment: this trick also works with `~`, saving an additional byte [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y6vTiOvLk9TT0@Pq842LTMn539uYoEGUEIjJbO4ICexUiNNI09T07qgKDOvJCdPQ1NTR0HDUMdYx1RT8z8A "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>70</s> 62 bytes

This is the simplest I can come up with.

```
for(;$i++<$n=$argv[1];)$F=array_fill(0,$n,$F?:$n);print_r($F);
```

Takes the input as the first argument and prints the resulting array on the screen.

---

Thanks to [@user59178](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59178/user59178) for saving me **8 bytes**!

Comment: Pre-assigning variables like that is unnecessary, as is `$l`. Dropping the `$i=0,` & replacing `$l`with `$n`  saves 7 bytes. An additional byte can be saved by not assigning `$F`, assigning `$n` in the conditional and using a ternary `$F?:$n` in the `array_fill()`

Comment: @user59178 I don't know if this is what you had in mind or not, but, thank you for the tips. You've saved me 8 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{($^n,{$_ xx$n}...*)[$n]}
```

Starts with `n`, and iteratively applies the "repeat n times" transformation `n` times, each time creating an additional level of `List` nesting.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#y61UUEtTsP1fraESl6dTrRKvUFGhklerp6enpRmtkhdb@784sVIhTcHQmgvCMIIxjGEME@v/AA)

Comment: Use `$_` instead to save a byte

Comment: @JoKing: I already use `$_` as the inner block's parameter, so I can't use it as the outer block's parameter as well.

Comment: Yes, but `$n` and `$_` always have the same value. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkMlXqdaJV6hokIlvlZPT09LM1olPrb2f3FipUKagqE1F4RhBGMYwxgm1v8B "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 36 bytes

```
#(nth(iterate(fn[a](repeat % a))%)%)
```

Iterates function which repeats its argument `n` times, it produces infinite sequence of such elements and then takes its `n`th element.

[See it online](https://ideone.com/l9pMOD)

Answer (score 3):

## Rebol, 45 bytes

```
func[n][array/initial append/dup copy[]n n n]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 49 bytes

```
(defmacro r[n]`(->> ~n ~@(repeat n`(repeat ~n))))
```

Not the shortest Clojure example, but I amused myself with the quoting and unquoting.

Answer (score 3):

## [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage), 7 bytes

I got this from my colleague, the creator of I.

```
#Bbhph~
```

`#Bb`     the copy `#` function **B**ound to **b**inding

   `hp`   **h**ook the argument to (the right of) the **p**ower function (repeat)

     `h~` **h**ook the argument to the left `~` (of the entire resulting function)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/i#@2@soKeg7JSUUZBR9/8/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, <s>128 102 95</s> 79 bytes

```
(defun f(x &optional y)(if(if y(< y 2))x(fill(make-list x)(f x(if y(1- y)x)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#VYsxCoAwEAR7X7GV3BUWRks/I@jBYYyiES6vjxGrLNsMs5tpWeUJEDK0xxn1CLNHYlIpRaIJCY7ZSNR72udt7bzeEcYksH/Td@Vh/KWh89IQUWRfkatoqGhkzvkF)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Fи
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7cKO//@NAA) or [verify the first \$[1,5]\$ test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/X@3Czv@1x5er8MFEuYqz8jMSVUoSk1MUcjM40rJ51JQ0M8vKNGH6IZSaAbaKKiA1eal/jfkMuIy5jLhMuUCAA)<sup>*†*</sup>.

<sup>*†*: Uses a Bash script to execute the 05AB1E code, so it'll use the (implicit) input within the test suite. If the number would be on the stack instead of as input, it won't work for \$n=2\$ (no idea why..): [see this traditional test suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q6mevpPCobZKCkr2fix4Y/ne7sON/rc5/AA), where every output is correct except for \$n=2\$.</sup>

**Explanation:**

```python
F   # Loop the (implicit) input amount of times:
 и  #  Repeat the (implicit) input the current values amount of times (as list)
    # (after which the resulting nested list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## tinylisp, 76 bytes

Since tinylisp was our most recent LYAL, I figured I had to at least post one answer in the lang. Embarrassingly, this answer (in a golfing dialect of lisp) is just as long as the Common Lisp solution

```
(load library
(d _(q((N D $)(i D(_ N(s D 1)(repeat-val $ N))$
(q((N)(_ N N N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyNFIV6jUEPDT8FFQUVTI1PBRSNewU@jGMg11NQoSi1ITSzRLUvMUVBR8NPUVOECq9UEqQHB/0DtjqhCXBqOQJ0g0ghMGoNJE83/AA)

This defines a helper function `_` that takes three arguments, the number of times to repeat each layer `N`, the current depth of the iteration `D` (counting down, so deepest depth is zero), and an accumulator `$`. Depending on depth, this function either returns the accumulator (at depth zero), or uses the library builtin `repeat-val` to repeat the current accumulator `N` times, and passes that on to the next depth of the recursion. Then the actual function, `A`, is defined, which takes a single argument `N` in, and calls `_` with that as all three arguments.

### Non-library solution, 86 bytes

This was my first attempt to do this, without using the builtin library (which has rather ungolfy names), but it unfortunately turned out rather longer.

```
(d _(q((X N D I $)(i D(i I(_ X N D(s I 1)(c X $))(_ $ N(s D 1)N()))X
(q((N)(_ N N N N(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyrDoAwDEU9X1ExcSt5/MCSmZnquQkwSwiBDMPXj3ZI0vQk9zS9dzmevdSzNWyUcQGJhAJFcoxCQTciU5eoqkfGqtExq3YkKoNKATOnwQrELvINrNb/7ACvP8apc@5cuL0)

This works much the same as the library solution, but manually defines the behavior of `repeat-val`, which requires taking two extra arguments in the helper function, which takes the value `X` the current depth is repeating, the number of repetitions on each depth `N`, the current depth `D` (counting down to zero), the number of repetitions remaining in this depth `I`, and an accumulator `$`. The proper function `A` works much the same, taking `N` calling `_` with the proper arguments. (in this case `N` for the first four, and nil `()` for the accumulator)

Comment: Here's a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco7CsAgFETRPqt4hcW8IkU@GxCs3YIYtBAkMSYEXL1RGbgwcN5wlhieVCviZR3FcGSbywRHBjegSZFgBFIwpPG0uzCyT96@82cjCdLMons5PHfXVyEbnVrX0W105/oD "tinylisp – Try It Online") link. Also, since anonymous function solutions are allowed, [you don't have to include the `(d A` in your solution](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24390/16766) (though you do still need it for TIO).

Comment: @DLosc oh ty for the TIO link! I meant to add it when posting, but it slipped my mind, also good shout about making the actual function anonymous

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
↯▽..
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=f%20%E2%86%90%20%E2%86%AF%E2%96%BD..%0A%0Af%201%0Af%202%0Af%203)

```
↯▽..
   .  # duplicate
  .   # duplicate
 ▽    # keep
↯     # reshape
```

Comment: A fun one: `|1 ⍥|'↯|..` (repeat `reshape n` n times to n). Also `⍥'↯,..` that leaves n below the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## ***Perl 6, 61 bytes***

```
my $x=prompt(0);my @a=$x xx$x;"@a=[@a] xx $x;".EVAL xx$x-1;
```

Big rippof from the Python 2 answer, but converted :P

Comment: Instead of `my $x=prompt(0);`, you can use `$_=get;`. You also need to print or return the result somehow, but note that the [rules of this site](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top) allow writing answers as functions or lambdas instead of of full programs, which is usually shorter in Perl 6.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 63 bytes

```clojure
#(loop[a(repeat % %)d 1](if(= d %)a(recur(repeat % a)(inc d))))
```

This is a lambda function, usage is like so:

```
(#(...) {input_no})
```

...where `{input_no}` is replaced with the number.

Output for `3` is like this:

```
(((3 3 3) (3 3 3) (3 3 3)) ((3 3 3) (3 3 3) (3 3 3)) ((3 3 3) (3 3 3) (3 3 3)))
```

This uses Clojure's definition of lists, which are denoted as `()`.

### Ungolfed code and explanation:

```clojure
; Defines the function
(defn layered [n]
  ; Begins a loop with a variable depth of 1,
  ; and a list of n elements which are all n
  (loop [depth 1
         array (repeat n n)]
    ; If "depth" is equal to n, return the list
    (if (= depth n) array
      ; Else, continue on with the loop, with
      ; an incremented "depth"...
      (recur (inc depth)
        ; ...and a list which contains the
        ; list repeated n times
        (repeat n array)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 59 bytes

```
	DEFINE('F(N)')
F	F =ARRAY(DUPL(N ',',N - 1) N,N)	:(RETURN)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfnPaaXhovmf08XVzdPPVUPdTcNPU12Ty43TTcHWMSjIMVLDJTTAR8NPQV1HXcdPQVfBUFPBT8dPE6gtyDUkNMhP878LumZO/9CQgNAQBVs3DVNNG2MdKLTjcvVz@Q8A)

Defines a function that returns an `ARRAY` with the appropriate dimensions and filled with value `N`.

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC), 53 bytes

Since C "has" multidimensional arrays (i.e. chunks of memory plus automatic offset calculation), this is almost a reasonable solution. Still, it's mostly a joke and borders on non-competing.

```c
f(n){int s=pow(n,n),*p=malloc(s*8);wmemset(p,n,s);}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##nVJhb5swEP1MfsU10xabkikJ@TAtYX@EWZFjILEGBsVk1dby15fZZxima1WpkpHx@fnde3cnlichbreCKPooVQs6aeoHoiJFo7BJKl6WtSA6/EJ3D1Ve6bwlTaQiTXfdbfZBKlFesxz2us2yvPh8/jaNydqGZj9rmUFzMfQHfrkQceYXCCPQ8nd@aIc9ZXTnIwXX@SEmVlMaM7cM4mUy8zfwQJY37Xk8yUobanicBbIAgpeQJLDCUIBEBZl/zOYRhATThRQMHzXJgm4W5KXOHfTa2mRkkS7sVdAn0D9kAwmmq00CQ4C3RX0BclVanlSegaVtam1w6x3@7J1Md7g3YScnQLYwcbLNHbNc3cDXp5SGZ7Uz297hVswePJaxPOaDe3MZos7IZYUlrCP4hG/XDOVicTxCC@nJRuORM456Or8ibOGK1c1e6aCRwX@NbbTEviHuDHGTP7bbaMVHHR3q6FBH37APEw4mHEz4MHRJODyZ108gKNz9GwTfJ/Q@0eSzGXFOOEuPLBVsUg/0b91WXCpiC4HUlt1GSVhfW5pumNFHXMCeKBRkgzxDns1XmI8BbGM/5hQMRQSbaDCLk22Om849GBx8V31H/gs9U4P98AX1DSpIPNEUv6UpnmqKMRK/LGtkBVJxdeUlndL3k2MVvs/WlrnlOxti1tx2ImP7lrnt1NwWI3a9Vvbu9kcUJT/p27Ks/gI)

In the TIO I go through the ceremony of casting the result (which is an `int`) to the appropriate array type despite the fact that my array print function (appropriately) takes a generic pointer.

While I can't demonstrate that the structure of the array is determined by `f` (it's not), I do include a flat printout of the elements of the output for an input of 3 using the multidimensional array element access syntax, to show that the layout of the returned memory matches that of the corresponding array type.

### Byte count

- function: 51 bytes
- compiler flags (`-lm`): 2 bytes

### Unportability

- The result pointer is returned through an `int`, so this may not work for all heap addresses.
- By using `wmemset` I require that the sizes of `int` and `wchar_t` are equal, and the scaling in the argument to `malloc` requires the sizes to be at most 8 bytes.
- Implicit declaration madness. I don't even know why passing `int`s to an unprototyped `pow` that actually takes `double`s seems to work correctly.
- The function "returns" by (I think) just leaving the return value of `wmemset` in the proper register. This behavior may be particular to the x86 architecture.

Comment: 42 bytes `s;f(n){wmemset(malloc(4*s),n,s=pow(n,n));}`

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice. But as far as I know neither C nor GCC defines the order of argument evaluation--what guarantees that will work?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
_òU}g[UpU ÆUÃ]
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X/JVfWdbVXBVIMZVw10=&input=NAotUQ==)

Output is wrapped in an extra singleton array.

Explanation:

```
          Æ Ã     #Create an array
           U      #Where every element is U
      UpU         #And the length is U^U
_  }g[       ]    #Repeat this function U times:
 òU               # Cut into slices of length U
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X/JVfWdbVXBVIMZVw10=&input=NAotUQ==); I was hoping it'd be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
{(x#x)#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWqFCu0FSuqOXi4kpTMARiIyA2BmITAHCYBrY=)

There's probably a way to make this tacit.

Comment: Variation to make tacit: `#/3#`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 89 Bytes

```
def f(x):
 r=[x for _ in range(x)]
 for _ in range(x-1):r=[r for _ in range(x)]
 print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 82 bytes

```
(def f #N::((def i #N,I,K::((if(> I 0)((i N(- I 1)(list-fill N K)))K)))(i N N N)))
```

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/ide2/index.html?code=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)

I tried implementing this as a list comprehension, but couldn't comprehend how to do it correctly. Instead I went for an implementation based on the JavaScript answer. Unfortunately, my language is fairly long-winded, and this is complicated by the fact that I lack shorthand and other useful features.

A more readable version is available at the [Try it Online](https://andrakis.github.io/ide2/index.html?code=JSBBIHZhbGlkIGVudHJ5IGZvciBDb2RlR29sZjoKJSBodHRwOi8vY29kZWdvbGYuc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb20vcXVlc3Rpb25zLzExMTY3OC9uLWRpbWVuc2lvbmFsLW5uLWFycmF5LWZpbGxlZC13aXRoLW4KKAogICAgJSBEZWZpbmUgb3VyIGZ1bmN0aW9uCiAgICAoZGVmIGYgI046OigKICAgICAgICAlIERlZmluZSBvdXIgaW5uZXIgZnVuY3Rpb24KICAgICAgICAoZGVmIGkgI04sSSxLIDo6ICgKICAgICAgICAgICAgKGlmICg+IEkgMCkgKAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJSBDYWxsIHNlbGYgKGhlYWQgcmVjdXJzaW9uKSB3aXRoIHVwZGF0ZWQgcGFyYW1ldGVycwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgKGkgTiAoLSBJIDEpIChsaXN0LWZpbGwgTiBLKSkKICAgICAgICAgICAgKQogICAgICAgICAgICAlIGVsc2UgcmV0dXJuIEsKICAgICAgICAgICAgKEspKQogICAgICAgICkpCiAgICAgICAgJSBJbnZva2UgaW5uZXIgZnVuY3Rpb24KICAgICAgICAoaSBOIE4gTikKICAgICkpCiAgICAlIEdvbGZlZDoKICAgIChkZWYgZiAjTjo6KChkZWYgaSAjTixJLEs6OigoaWYoPiBJIDApKChpIE4oLSBJIDEpKGxpc3QtZmlsbCBOIEspKSlLKSkpKGkgTiBOIE4pKSkKICAgIAogICAgJSBUZXN0aW5nIHRoZSBmdW5jdGlvbgogICAgKHByaW50IChmIDEpKQogICAgKHByaW50IChmIDIpKQogICAgKHByaW50IChmIDMpKQogICAgJSBOb3RlIHRoYXQgYmV5b25kIGxldmVsIDMsIHlvdSBuZWVkIHRvIHVzZSBgaW5zcGVjdCAuLi4gdHJ1ZWAgdG8gZ2V0CiAgICAlIGZ1bGwgb3V0cHV0LgogICAgKHByaW50IChpbnNwZWN0IChmIDQpIHRydWUpKQogICAgKHByaW50IChpbnNwZWN0IChmIDUpIHRydWUpKQogICAgKHByaW50IChpbnNwZWN0IChmIDYpIHRydWUpKQop) link.

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 56 bytes

```
|=
n/@
=+
i=1
|-
?:
=(n i)
(reap n n)
(reap n $(i +(i)))
```

Create a new function that takes an atom `n`. Make a variable `i` starting at 1, and start a loop: if `i==n` return a list with `n` elements of `n`, else return a list with `n` elements of the value returned by recursing to the start of the loop with `i = i + 1`.

I'm a little bit upset that there's not really anything you can do to golf this in Hoon :/ The standard trick of using unnamed variables doesn't apply because it's longer to use lark syntax for once, due to the loop shifting the location of `i`.

```
> =f |=
  n/@
  =+
  i=1
  |-
  ?:
  =(n i)
  (reap n n)
  (reap n $(i +(i)))
> (f 1)
~[1]
> (f 2)
~[~[2 2] ~[2 2]]
> (f 3)
~[~[~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3]] ~[~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3]] ~[~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3] ~[3 3 3]]]
> (f 4)
~[
  ~[
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
  ]
  ~[
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
  ]
  ~[
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
  ]
  ~[
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
    ~[~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4] ~[4 4 4 4]]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 34 bytes

```
#:(x){<<j=[x]*x#i:1->x j=[j]*x/>j}
#:(x){<<j=[x]*x#i:1->x j=[j]*x/>j}(2) // [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://felixguo.me/?code=IzooeCl7PDxqPVt4XSp4I2k6MS0+eCBqPVtqXSp4Lz5qfSgyKQ==#wendyScript)

Comment: Is it not possible to have the link actually populate with the your code?

Comment: I will have to add that functionality, I'll get back to you in 30 minutes but that's a good point.

Comment: @Adám updated link

Answer (score 1):

## 12-basic, 42 bytes

```
A=[N=INPUT()]*N
FOR I=2TO N
A=[A]*N
NEXT?A
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 14 bytes

```
é,"aPÀñDÀpys0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKHaXEgMMNhze6HG4oqCw2iP3//78JAA)

input

```
é,               # write comma
  "aP            # paste register A (input)
     Àñ          # loop À (number in register A) times
       D         # cut to end of line
        Àp       # paste À times
          ysB]   # surround everything before comma in square brackets
```

Comment: This prints a trailing comma..

Comment: @BMO is the trailing comma a problem? it was never explicitly stated that it wasn't allowed.  if it is a problem I can change it, it just adds one or two characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 12 bytes

```
YaLaY[y]RLay
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MtEnMTK6MjbIJ7Hy////ugX/jQE)

#### Explanation

```
YaLaY[y]RLay
Y             Yank into the y variable
 a            the first command-line argument, a
  La          Fixed-iterations loop, do the following a times:
     [y]       y wrapped in a list
        RLa    repeated a times (results in a list containing a copies of y)
    Y          Yank that list back into y
           y  After the loop, print y
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `arrays.shaped`, 39 bytes

```
[ 3 dupn <array> swap repeated-shaped ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7CsJAFET7fMX8gAs@KhVbsbERq5DikoxmMd6sdzdIFL99DWI1nANnLlKn3vL5dDju17hSadL5lyTfa4SYyRhxoym7P7nYSmCDyMdArRkRjCmNwbwm@B6bonhjjgWWWOGTy2mbISi2v36H@JQAY6AkNrP/W5Xvky3hnIN2qECp2/wF)

`repeated-shaped` Takes a sequence of dimensions (i.e. a shape) and an element and creates an array from them. The rest of the code turns `4` into `{ 4 4 4 4 } 4`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḷⱮ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju2PNq47tPD///8mAA)

Like Lynn's solution which heavily inspired this, a full program only.

```
  ¡    Repeat [input] times, starting with the input on the left and right:
 Ɱ     Produce an array containing, for every element of the right argument,
ḷ      the left argument.
```

Although dyadic `¡`, rather than reusing its right argument, uses the previous left argument for each successive iteration, in this case either behavior would do the same thing--since each intermediate result has the same length as the (implicitly rangified) initial input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes

```
n->for(i=1,a=n,a=vector(n,x,a));a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBCoAwDAS/Ejw1kB4K3iT9SxBbcomlFPH3MR52YGaHTM19eAN2y7XdMykXErbYc50rgtFLgniI/7cBQyHYCcZUW@Eb5BpoyRDRPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
(ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIo4bqLIiwiIiwiMyJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 150 bytes

```go
func f(n int)[]any{return g(n,n)}
func g(n,d int)(L[]any){if d<1{return}
for i:=0;i<n;i++{var e any
if d<2{e=n}else{e=g(n,d-1)}
L=append(L,e)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9NasMwEIX3OsVgCEjYCUmhEBKru-y86D7tQsSSGVqPjSoHivA1ssnGFHqIHqW36UQ1ZDN_fLz35vrVdNNPb05vprHQGiSBbd_5sMpcG7LvIbjl9vfiBjqBkwRIQR1fDX1Gb8PgCRpJBalRJOK21ImRVaJURAd1uZlpxjoPuNPrPZa0xzyPZ-PBAqMikQ_Rahrt-4flIcktN6xeadP3lmpZFZbXWW1Od0jet-xSQbxbAJb6kWue8_XZcywns0UN-gkW5xfKCsCCn0KlxChmsWn6738)

Call with `f(n)`. Returns an `[]any`, that can be casted to a `f(n).([]int)`,`f(n).([][]int)`,`f(n).([][][]int)`,`f(n).([][][][]int)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 4 bytes

```
⥊˜⥊⊢
```

Anonymous tacit function; takes an integer and returns an N-dimensional array. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4qWKy5zipYriiqIKCkYgMw==)

#### Explanation

Exactly the same as [Dennis's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111691/16766), though independently derived.

The [Reshape](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/reshape.html#reshape) builtin `⥊` takes a shape (list of integer dimensions) on the left and an array of values on the right. It creates an array of the given shape, filled with values taken from the original array. If either argument is a bare integer, it is promoted to a list containing that integer.

With example argument 3:

`⥊˜` reshapes the argument with itself as the shape. The result is a 3-element 1-dimensional array of 3's: `⟨ 3 3 3 ⟩`.

`⊢` returns the argument unchanged: `3`.

So `⥊˜ ⥊ ⊢` is equivalent to `⟨ 3 3 3 ⟩ ⥊ 3`: reshape `3` into a 3 by 3 by 3 array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
{Wọ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS6vDH-7uXVKclFwMFVmw0BjCAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
{Wọ  # Implicit input
{    # Repeat input number of times:
 W   #  Wrap top of stack into a list
  ọ  #  Repeat input number of times
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 34 bytes

```perl
sub{eval'@_=[(@_)x$x];'x($x="@_")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6tSwxR90h3jZawyFes0KlItZavUJDpcJWySFeSbP2vzVXaXGqgktiSaKVlUtpbkFqkTVXQVFmXokChKeSpmunYWOn@d8EAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 85 bytes

```
function f(n,d,x)d=d or 2 x={}for i=1,n do x[i]=d>n and n or f(n,d+1)end return x end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBBbsMgELz7FSNOoCKraW@V6EeqHkiBFMVdW3htuYrydhcoSU@9rJaZnZldhsXue1jog@NICJK005tyxmFMeMJmLteQu2gOmuBGbG/x3bhXgiUHKkNV83BQPgPJ85IIG/Kj6@62PKVILPk4aERynlh1QAygkRsA/vR06w0eqwNQss8aa2Yw2ZjmYqLyIpmr7JdljnTKkplzyKlPfpICEPck9D3OpYgXiCrLwfw9ebkqGAPB9jh4UReoNPC77p@7ani7Y71556sr44fZ/yMtwWubqheVWn@nmQX5rNS@/wA)

(The TIO link contains a bit of extra code to print the table as Lua has no built-in way of printing a table's contents)

### Explanation

```
function f(n, d, x)
  d = d or 2
  x = {}
  for i = 1, n do
    x[i] = d > n and n or f(n, d + 1)
  end
  return x
end
```

As you can probably see, `f` is a recursive function which takes the number N as `n`, and two other arguments, `d` and `x`. `d` is the depth, and is not used in the initial call, in which case it defaults to 2. `x` is not actually used as a parameter, but is there because the function requires a temporary local variable, and it is shorter to declare it as a parameter than to use the `local` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), 74 bytes

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@O@ooVnNVZpXnFqikKmQpZCtUPU/DSiUll8E5GtUG@rpqRjWalZp22qoGGla29jYaKhUadZygeSzEPLZtglpCiqGCirV2Va6QIEEkEqV7P@1XI4KhkBsBMTG/wE)

```bash
f(){for i ({1..$1})z+=($2);<<<($z)}
for j ({1..$1})k=`f $1 ${k:-$1}`;<<<$k
```

Zsh doesn't have multi dimensional arrays but it can do arrays of strings. Here we build up string `$k` by plugging it into `f`, then taking that result as the new `$k`, iterating N times (`$1`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```
$=>[@.of:@.of:<=<=&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?bRzacS)

#### Huh?

In Arturo, you can initialize a block of values like this:

```arturo
array.of: 5 2    ; [2 2 2 2 2]
```

You can also give it a shape:

```arturo
array.of: [5 3] 2    ; [[2 2 2] [2 2 2] [2 2 2] [2 2 2] [2 2 2]]
```

`@` is syntax sugar for `array`.

`$=>` is syntax sugar for `function [n]`.

`<=<=&` Means push the input to the stack and duplicate it twice.

So putting it all together, `$=>[@.of:@.of:<=<=&]` is the same as:

```arturo
function [n][
    array.of: array.of: n n n
]
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```arturo
function [n][
    shape: array.of: n n
    return array.of: shape n
]
```