# Turn an integer n into a list containing it n times

Tags: code-golf, number, array, integer

Given an integer `n` as input, return a list containing `n`, repeated `n` times. For example, the program would take `5` and turn it into `[5,5,5,5,5]`. The elements need to be integers, not strings. No built-in functions that accomplish the task are allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard rules apply.

Comment: Why no builtins?

Comment: @Okx I meant built-in functions which already do this, must have used the wrong word, i'll edit the post.

Comment: I edited the question such that it is a bit more readable and fits our standard format better.

Comment: Should `n=0` be supported?

Comment: @BrunoE That still doesn’t answer the _why_. Do you have an actual reason to ban built-ins? To quote xnor: [In general, if your challenge is too simple to be interesting, it won't be saved by banning things.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8079#8079)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111678/n-dimensional-nn-array-filled-with-n)

Comment: With your current prohibition on built-ins, is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139829/43319) valid?

Comment: Does it matter? This is meant to be fun, we can have different opinions on what is and isn't valid.

Comment: @BrunoE while I agree with the sentiment, we prefer objectivity here at ppcg. Either something is or is not valid, opinions shouldn't come into the equation.

Comment: @BrunoE The specs *must* be made such that one can indisputably decide whether an entry is valid or not. Please share your thoughts on the existing answers and make the specs more objective when it comes to `built-in`.

Comment: in which case, I'll (begrudgingly) say the entry is invalid.

Comment: @Lynn then let the challenge be considered 'uninsteresting'. Nobody is under any obligation to answer, but a fair number of people seem to have found it interesting enough.

Comment: Along with @Arnauld's comment, can we assume the input is non-negative?

Comment: I'm still confused what counts as a "built-in" for this task. Is Python's `*` operator ok? What's an example of a built-in that isn't ok?

Comment: I am suprised nobody has mentioned this yet, but we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for challenges where you can post them to get feedback on them, before they go live. This way you might've prevented discussing the rules of the challenge while others already submitted their answers.

Comment: Can we leave the output on the stack for stack based languages, or do we have to print it?

Answer (score 33):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/i////pgA)

Note that this is **not** the “repeat `n` `n` times” built-in — its function is more general than that. For example `4,5,6x1,2,3` equals `[4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]`. Given only one argument, Jelly just happens to use it as both the left and right argument for the supplied link, but this functionality is not *inherent* to `x`.

If this doesn’t count, there are various fun 2-byte alternatives:

```
x` ṁ` Ra Rị R» a€ oR oḶ oṬ oẊ Ḷị Ḷ» Ṭị Ṭ» Ẋị Ẋ» ị€ ṛ€ ȧ€ »€
```

etc.

Comment: *No built-in functions that accomplish the task are allowed.* While `x` may be more general, it is indeed a built-in function that accomplishes the task.

Comment: Well, yes. Every code golf answer is a collection of built-ins that accomplish the task. You might ban this answer if `x` did “all the work”, but it most certainly doesn’t — there’s an implicit “0 bytes” of link-parsing and array-coercion logic going on to turn this into `repeat([n], n)`, which is exactly what other answers do.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Who cares about intention? `x` is a built-in function. `x` accomplishes the task. No built-in function that accomplish the task are allowed. Therefore, `x` is not allowed.

Comment: @Lynn The fact that that is Jelly's normal way of treating missing arguments is exactly what makes `x` prohibited. APL's `/` (the grandfather of Jelly's `x`) and J's `#` (the father of Jelly's `x`) are not prohibited because they need `⍨` and `~` respectively to explicitly use the input as both count and data.

Comment: @Adám I think the difference lies in that this is not the function of the `x` command. When used in different cases, it provides different effects; it's no different than a J or APL answer with an implicit `~` or similar at the end of the program.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien But it is. A complete documentation for `x` would have read *when applied to one or more numbers, it returns a list where each element Xₙ is expanded to Xₙ copies of itself*.

Comment: @Adám This is the "repeat each element of x y times" function, taking 2 arguments. What makes it accomplish the task is how Jelly parses implicit arguments, which has nothing to do with the function itself.

Comment: If this answer is invalid then the constraint of the question is not "No builtins" it is "No 1 byte answers", which is an extremely arbitrary limitation that seems counterproductive in code golf.

Comment: I think an argument towards this not being a built-in is that there are two other 1 byte answers in Jelly that do the same thing `ṁ` and `ẋ` so this answer could be any one of the three.  There aren't 3 built-ins (one would hope) for "repeat `n` `n` times", so they can't ALL be a "built-in" for it.

Comment: @nmjcman101 I disagree. In [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139837/43319) you see three built-ins that almost do the task; they just need to be told to use a single argument twice. This "telling" is built into Jelly. Whether you call it part of its primitives or part of the language is just a matter of semantics. All three are Jelly built-ins for the exact job. Compare to multiplication and minimum on Booleans. Wouldn't both be prohibited in a challenge to AND two Booleans without built-ins for the exact task?

Comment: @Adám I would say that multiplication and minimum are not builtins for boolean AND, even if they complete a challenge which requested boolean AND. Perhaps this should be made a meta-post for further discussion?

Comment: @KamilDrakari K has a single built-in `&` [labelled `min|and`](http://kparc.com/k.txt).

Comment: @Adám I've posted [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13771/71434) meta post for further discussion on this topic.

Comment: This whole comment thread seems a good argument for not banning something as subjective as builtins.

Answer (score 22):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 14 bytes

```python
lambda k:[k]*k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjo7Viv7f1p@kUKmQmaeQlFiXnqqhoGOoaGmFZdCQVFmXolGpo66rp26TppGpqbmfwA)

Comment: What's wrong with just `[n]*n`?

Comment: @paxdiablo That is a snippet. We can create either full programs or functions as per the meta consensus.

Answer (score 19):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language,  <s>50</s>  46 bytes

```
f={a=[];t=_this;while{count a<t}do{a=a+[t]};a}
```

**Call with:**

```
hint format["%1", 5 call f]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have post decrement, `i--`, and `+=` in this?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Why are the screenshots for this always in a barren desert? You should use a cool map for your screenshots :P.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Is that better?

Comment: @Steadybox ahaha! Epic :P. Is that the town from left for dead? That looks like the church you start in kinda.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No, it's just a town from one of the game's original maps.

Comment: I always upvote OPFP

Comment: I think the screenshots should be posted cropped to a smaller image. We don't need to see the map, and it distracts from the actual output.

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes

Five equally short solutions. Last two are courtesy of [Zacharý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%c3%bd).

---

```apl
⍴⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR24RHvVse9a4AshVMAQ)

`⍴` cyclically **r**eshape

`⍨` self

---

```apl
/⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR2wT9R70rgCwFUwA)

`/` replicate

`⍨` self

---

```apl
\⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR24SYR70rgCwFUwA)

`\` expand

`⍨` self

---

```apl
⌿⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR24RHPfsf9a4AshVMAQ)

`⌿` replicate along first (and only) axis

`⍨` self

---

```apl
⍀⍨
```

`⍀` expand along first (and only) axis

`⍨` self

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR24RHvQ2PelcA2QqmAA)

Comment: @Uriel There's one more…

Comment: Both `⌿⍨` and `⍀⍨` work.

Comment: Was it intentional that 'self' looks like a face?

Comment: @geokavel I don't think so, but I also noticed it as a typed this post. Makes it pretty mnemonic, no? In fact, *selfie* is one of its semi-official names, so in the RIDE interface to Dyalog APL, you can insert `⍨` by typing *``selfie*.

Comment: ⍀ and ⍨ are each three-byte characters. TIO does report the bytesize correctly. I feel like you should know this.

Comment: @sethrin TIO counts characters (and UTF-8 bytes where applicable), but it is up to the user to ensure that they do not use any characters that are missing from a single-byte character set (SBCS). [For APLs, see here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

Comment: @Adám thanks for the correction. I'll have to read more about APL's charset.

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
#~Table~#&
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 8 bytes

```
n=>[n]*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/P1i46L1Yr739BUWZeiUaahqmm5n8A)

Comment: This combines the best of the python answer and the javascript answer, I love it!

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

```js
n=>Array(n).fill(n)
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>Array(n).fill(n)
)(i.value=8);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: An array without `...` - whatever next?!

Comment: @Neil: it felt wrong even as I was typing it! :D

Answer (score 9):

## Octave, 12 bytes

```matlab
@(n)~(1:n)+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs07D0CpPUzvvf2JesYap5n8A)

Comment: What does the ~ in octave, because that's the only part of your code I don't understand..

Comment: @Michthan Sorry for late reply. `~` is the  `not` operator that converts 1:n to an array of  `0`s of size n. You can use `!` instead of it.

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 2 bytes

```
*]
```

**[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a%5D&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0).**

---

```
*]QQ - Full program with implicit input

 ]   - Turn the input into a list.
*    - Repeat it a number of times equal to the input.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 13 bytes

```hs
f n=n<$[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzbPRiXaUE8vL/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoLpfwA) Usage: `f 5` yields `[5,5,5,5,5]`. For `n=5`, `[1..n]` yields the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. `n<$` replaces each element of this list with `n`.

Comment: Mine's a bit longer, but I like it anyway: `join replicate`

Comment: @amalloy This would indeed be the clean Haskell way to do it. However, `join` is not part of Prelude and thus requiers a lengthy `import Control.Monad`, which rarely makes it useful for golfing.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
array(n<-scan(),n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7GoKLFSI89Gtzg5MU9DUydP87/pfwA)

Comment: Is `rep(n<-scan(),n)` too close to a builtin?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Maybe you should post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Fˆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7XTb//@mAA)

Comment: Nice, better than `.D)`.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Yeah, that was my first thought.

Answer (score 5):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 76 bytes

```
	f f r 2
2
	
	
r
	r d
	f s t f
d
	dip f s t
	f
t
	dot f
	dot
s
	s dip
f
	dab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCoBADEPXzSlyhll4H6UUXFVa718zEsjnxdOzZywYLC4smFSwokO0@TKg6vfDf4pC5rmPHWhYUz/2Pq@ZOT4)

## Explanation:

`f` is an alias for `dab` (tail).

`s` is subtraction, as explained on the wiki: **(x, y) → (0, y−x)** when **x ≤ y**.

`t` maps **(a, b, c…)** to **(b+c+…, a+b+c+…)**.

`f s t` maps **(a, b, c…)** to **a**. This is our “head” function.

`d` dips only the head of its argument: **(a, b, c…) → (|a−1|, b, c…)**

`r` is the main repetition logic. We map **(a, b)** to **(*r(|a−1|, b), b)**.

For example, **r(4, 7)** will evaluate as

```
  r(4, 7)
= r(3, 7), 7
= r(2, 7), 7, 7
= r(1, 7), 7, 7, 7
= r(0, 7), 7, 7, 7, 7
  → This would call r(1, 7), but (1, 7) ≥ (0, 7), so surrender!
= 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7.
```

Finally, we define `2`, which maps **n → (n, n)**, and define `main` as `f f r 2`, computing **r(n, n)** and chopping off the first two elements.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 2 bytes

```
ÆU
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xlU=&input=OA==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`. Generate an array of integers from `0` to `U-1`. Fill it with `U`. Implicit output of resulting array.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @DomHastings

```perl
sub{(@_)x"@_"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n1upoJKmYPu/uDSpWsMhXrNCySFeqfa/NVdBUWZeiUJWfmaehpKOkg5Qla6dhqmmpo6CUkyekvV/AA)

Is `x` a builtin that does the entire task? Sort of? Not really? Rules unclear?

Edit: Yeah, probably it's fine.

Comment: Had pretty much the same, but you can change the first `$_[0]` to `@_`! Also the second can be`"@_"` I think...

Comment: I would say it doesn't count as a built-in because you have to work around the fact that it takes two inputs instead of one.

Comment: Why not `$_=$_ x$_` with `perl -pe`?

Comment: @Thor `x` does string repetition, not list repetition, unless the left operand is in parentheses (or is a `qw` operator) and the `x` is evaluated in list context.  And of course `$_` is a scalar, not a list.

Comment: I meant something like this: `echo 5 | perl -pe '$_=$_ x$_' `

Comment: @Thor I wouldn't count that as satisfying "return a list".

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```java
n->java.util.Arrays.stream(new int[n]).map(i->n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBasMwDD3HX6GjTVezndMVehnssO3QY@nBS53gLpGNrXQNI9@eKWnWQTcQPCG993jS0ZzM0geLx8PH4JrgI8GRZ7olV@tNjKZLufizKFssyHnUT3PzDydRtKbRz0jbqcuFCO177QooapMSvBiH4ktk8zCRIYaTdwdoeCVZ5bDa7cHEKimRMTUrfQTpkMDBI9znDCt4GHGxYMZEybZdItto35IO7EA1yssdmvzFU9Yu0Vv5Kp3i2bSUSqmc1b3gus10PQGuQo5wnjP9vGDFNFvZePfLX0PFOUU24HJ9@9X5PxLtJ7DdDvdKNyZIt1yjGsYs0VIbESptQqg7eR4D9qIfvgE)

*-2 bytes thanks to @Jakob*

Inspired by the comments in @OlivierGrégoire's post, and optimized a little further. Takes an integer input, creates an IntStream of `n` elements, then maps each element to `n` and returns it.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by starting with `java.util.Arrays.stream(new int[n])`.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell (14 bytes)

```
replicate>>=id
```

Thanks to @nimi, I don't need any import anymore. Yay!

It's a function that takes an integer argument; for example, the following returns `[5,5,5,5,5]`:

```
(replicate>>=id) 5
```

Comment: Why not `id=<<replicate`? It's also 14 bytes but doesn't need the import.

Comment: @nimi Very good point! Overlooked that possibility. (I really need to dive into the arrow monad more...)

Answer (score 4):

## TeX, 81 bytes

```
\newcommand{\f}[1]{#1\count0=2\loop,#1\advance\count0 by1\ifnum\count0<#1\repeat}
```

### Usage

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{#1\count0=2\loop,#1\advance\count0 by1\ifnum\count0<#1\repeat}

\f{5}

\f{10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's actually LaTeX. In Tex it'd be much shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
´R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CWoP///5sCAA)

```
´    -- Apply next function twice to same argument
 R   -- given an integer n and some element, replicate the element n-times
```

---

#### Polite alternative (3 bytes)

```
ṠIR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBZ5B////NwUA)

Answer (score 3):

## J, 2 bytes

```
$~
```

Same as the APL answer: reflexively shape the input. In other words:

```
$~ y
y $ y
NB. y copies of y
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainbash](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brainbash), 39 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>->#[->+>+<<]>>[-<;<<.>>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLSizO@P/fTjcaCG1i7ey0gYSunXK0rp02kA0SAYpb29jo2dnZxf7/bwoA)

Prints `N` `N` times. Works by generating 32, taking input, then duplicating the input twice, then output the first for each 1 in the second.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
int*f(k){int*r=malloc(k*4),a=k;for(;a-->0;)r[a]=k;k=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7bioMwEH3vVxwChUxrwEL7sqnth4gswa1LUGNJbGFX/HZ3ksLWvOScmXOZWn3X9bJYN@4a2dIUgS9603VDLdvdkTJTtLoZvNRGqUuuyZem4lFbeD0vz8F@wXhvfj7vnr0y@tHZMGZgiGB/b4QJMSByiwK55u@cVoz2e0KyNlJs7TaILNlLW2X/MigccAWvBD4gBGnMm1Q93kLqhIst7xyoC0rWO5auz2uko9f0/hiDFNUrKyb0xjpJ0wb8UmxO@k0Oa3JckxOTeTn9AQ)

Returns a list of `k` integers.

Comment: Yay "long arrow operator". Also, I didn't think gcc would ever use register `eax` for locals. Go figure.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing a comparison to 0 in for cycle, unless I've overlooked something.

Comment: Suggest `*f(k){int r[k],` instead of `int*f(k){int*r=malloc(k*4),`

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 10 bytes

```
{[[_]*_1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfxfzcWZpmBlqxDzvzo6Oj5WK94wtvZ/LRdXbmJmngJQsqAoM69EoaC0OEPDVFOhRiFNQ5Or9j8A)

Explanation:

```
{[[_]*_1]}
{        } /* Anonymous function   */
   _       /* The input (_1)       */
  [ ]      /* As a list            */
     *_1   /* Repeated _1 times    */
 [      ]  /* Pushed to the stream */
```

Comment: Why can you leave off the 1 in the first input but not the second?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Each underscore without a number has a number that is one larger than the previous: `[_]*_` = `[_1]*_2`. Because the first underscore is the first, it has automatically the number 1.

Answer (score 3):

## Coreutils, sed, 14 bytes

```
yes $1|sed $1q
```

As a zsh function, <strike>20</strike> 19 bytes:

```
f(){yes $1|sed $1q}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/TUOzujK1WEHFsKY4NQVIFdb@T1Mw@w8A)

Comment: I don't think this answer is valid, since it doesn't take input.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: used it in a function

Comment: Why not just make it a program `yes $1|sed $1q`?

Comment: Good point @DigitalTrauma, updated

Comment: The rules say it has to be integer elements, not string elements.  To satisfy that, a bash/zsh answer would need to use `declare -i` integer variables.  But it also has to be an array.  I'm not sure bash even supports an integer array (like `eval declare -ia "$1"` to use the first function arg as the name of an array return value.)  I upvoted this because it follows the spirit of the question; I doubt the question meant to exclude languages that don't really have integer lists / arrays.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
tY"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyRS6f9/UwA)

**Explanation:**

```
t       % duplicate elements
Y"      % replicate elements of array
        % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 9 bytes

```
{[it]*it}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/F9QlJlXkpOnofG/OjqzJFYrs6T2v6aGmaGm5n8A)

---

Perhaps the most competitive groovy answer I've done to date.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 16 bytes

```
[->+>+<<]>[->.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/q/zP1rXTttO28Ym1g7I0rOJ/f9fEQA)

### The breakdown:

```
[->+>+<<]          Duplicate 'n' into the next 2 cells to the right
         >         Move to the first duplicate
          [->.<]   Print 'n', 'n' times
```

As I'm sure you're aware,  brainfuck takes input and output values as ASCII characters. So a `!` is represented as the value 33.

Comment: Your program doesn't take input, I don't think. Unless you're talking about a value left on the tape

Comment: @ConorO'Brien The ladder. Think of it as a function more than a program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```java
n->{int a[]=new int[n],i=n;for(;i-->0;)a[i]=n;return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU9Na8MwDL33V@gY08WUXV0HdinssFOPIQctTYqyVA623BFKfntmN4UJhD7e4@lpwDuWbup4uPysU/weqYV2xBDgC4nhsQN4bYOgpHJ3dIFbwoqzeOJr3QD6a1CZCTAkOR2FRt1HboUc60@W06s/EkvdVNDblcvqkSbAurHc/UJGuHkjy6Z3vjBUltXBKKwp4cZ3Ej0DmmWFZ5jntczMIgQWDiaVo4X33Oz3CjZDAOc5SHfTLoqekmEZufh3@eE9zkGL254peo3TNM4FKaW2G8su57L@AQ)

-2 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen

Comment: Two bytes shorter: `n->{int a[]=new int[n],i=n;for(;i-->0;)a[i]=n;return a;}`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ouch, it hurts I didn't think about that... Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. ;) If you look in my answer history you'll probably also find some answers where I add something along the lines of "bytes saved thanks to ... due to a stupid mistake by myself / something obvious I forgot.." :)

Comment: I thought about an answer like `IntStream.generate(() -> n).limit(n)` but decided it wasn't worth typing up and upvoted this instead :)

Comment: @JollyJoker [You could do it](https://tio.run/##dY9Na8MwDIbv/RWiJ5sspuyaJrcNdtgpx7GDljqZUkc2tlIoo789c0PGYDCBkND76GvEC5Y@WB5P5yXMH4466BymBK9IDF87gK2aBCWHi6cTTFlTrUTi4e0dMA5JryjAmOeZWciZfuZOyLN5YXne8uOvnCRanO5iu2YN9PXCZfM/YQbLNqJYpXTZsDaOJhLFeoHVqvWA3kdFLED1oaJjDY@HCqgofu7LgMEQ3FWRNpl9wu5T5bXtNYmdjJ/FhPxWHgsF7B9gr3W1Nf5FHKtNu@3uflu@AQ)! It's indeed two bytes shorter and would easily beat my answer ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but it's also flat out the canonical correct way of doing that in Java 8 so it's a pretty boring answer

Comment: Isn't using `Arrays.fill(a,n)`wouldn't be shorter than looping? (I'm new to PPCG, don't know if java.util can be used).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès If you want to try that, compare the two following: `i=n;for(;i-->0;)a[i]=n;` and `java.util.Arrays.fill(a);` (yes, the full name is required). 23 bytes vs. 25 bytes. I think I'll keep the loop. But thanks anyways ;-)

Comment: Ok I was not aware about full name qualification. I tried to find the rules but wasn't able? Any hint please?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Here are a few links to allow you to start getting around here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf And specifically about imports: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8287/on-scoring-imported-functions

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 3](https://www.swift.org), 29 bytes

```swift
{n in(0..<n).map{_ in n}}
```

**[Try it here!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599ad86ca5f97c4ee18da7ff)**

## [Swift 3](https://www.swift.org), 30 bytes

```swift
{Array(repeating:$0,count:$0)}
```

**[Try it here!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599abf047a55b2295b134530)**

Comment: I wonder if we can get the input as the same variable repeated twice. Then you could have a 10 byte solution: `Array.init`. Just assign it to a variable with a type alias, and boom: `let f: (Int, Int) -> [Int] = Array.init; print(f(5, 5))`

Comment: @Alexander No, we cannot get the input twice.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```cs
n=>System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat(n,n)
```

Old version for 38 bytes:

```cs
n=>"".PadLeft(n,(char)n).ToCharArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU5BCsIwELznFUtPCa1FvaYtSMGDVCgoeBAPISa60G4gSYUivr2mzMAMM@wyOmxGR26ZAtILLnOIZpRMDyoE6NmXhagiavg4fMJZIXGRwuNEukKKBei38vdHAxbqheomy8pePTtjI6eCr6UgUV5dm9zBezVzsUhmnQeezgGhhp1MUtWw30rIc1zft46CG0x58xhNh2R4iD7NK08uDcgKSLQchRCS/VYsfw)

A `char` in C# is an `int` underneath so this appears to be valid.

---

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 44 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;n=>new int[n].Select(_=>n)
```

If the above is invalid this is for an extra 6 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwDIbvfgqxk01as/bqJJfSlo4OBj3sMMZIXaUIHJnazsYYffZMOQyGBEKf9Eu/z8shcpzGTHyF03cuODj1v7NH4ptTPnQ5w4v6Ubl0hTx8RrrAc0esjcDdyL4mLos/1SaGgL5Q5Gz3yJjI28OWxwFTdw4477Yt9NBM3LSMXyDgjd/tCWeZ/hBoJqf6mEDLCAgaWDkpdQPrRwdVRfPfjdyPAe1rooLiFHUuSczbpyjOHhYg2Wsyxjh1n2P6BQ)

Comment: Also 38 Bytes but more readable:
n=>new String((char)n,n).ToCharArray()

Comment: @TheJoeIaut So you're aware that would have to be `new string...` note the lower case :) Though yes it is the same length unfortunately.

Comment: 25: `n=>Enumerable.Repeat(n,n)`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Actually 37 but does save a byte thanks!

Comment: Oh, right - the `using`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Well you can fully qualify it here :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Tampio](https://github.com/fergusq/tampio), <s>109</s> 85 bytes

```
a:n uni on a a:na
nolla a:na on tyhjyys
a:n seuraaja o:na on o lisättynä a:han o:na
```

Explanation:

```
a:n uni on   a a:na
uni(a)  =  f(a,a)

  nolla a:na on tyhjyys
f(0,    a)   =  []

  a:n seuraaja o:na on o lisättynä a:han o:na
f(a   +1,      o)   =  o :       f(a,    o)

uni(a)   = f(a,a)
f(0  ,a) = []
f(a+1,o) = o : f(a,o)
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**, **19 Bytes**

I'm new here can anyone tell if this is ok ?

```
for(;$b--;)$a[]=$n;
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZ6uSZJuWnlpSrBEc4uLpp2nN9T8tv0jDWiVJV9daUyUxOtZWJc8aJJaamJyhoZKokFisoJJXmpuUWqTJVc3FmZqckQ8TsOaq/W8KAA)

EDIT:

looks to not be a valid form so :

**32 Bytes** (by Titus)

(+1 Byte for `R` flag)

```
for($b=$argn;$b--;)echo$argn,_;
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSep2CrYGrNpa@vkFSpkJyfm5uYl6KQk5mXqpCYkqKgG/Q/Lb9IQyXJFqzWWiVJV9daMzU5Ix/M11GPV7f@/98UAA)

Comment: Use Try It Online: https://tio.run/#php

Comment: @Nnnes it's better like this ?

Comment: Wellcome to PPGC. You need to use some form of input and output you're not allowed to handle that outside. Use e.g. $_GET, $argv, $argn or read from stdin. `for($a=$argn;$argn--;)$b[]=$a;echo implode(',',$b);` would work. `echo$a=$argn;for(;--$argn;)echo',',$a;` would be better though ;) You would be allowed to submit a function but they are usally longer in php :/

Comment: `function a($b){for($n=$b;$b--;)$a[]=$n;return$a;}` would be valid for example.

Comment: ... or `for($b=$argn;$b--;)echo$argn,_;` (and don´t forget to count +1 for the `R` flag)

Comment: @Titus i don't get it about the $argn and the flag, i understand that you do it by command line but i don't find a way to use input for command on tio.run (feel free to edit if it's necessary)

Comment: afaik, TiO cannot handle `$argn`. Just define a variable with that name in the header.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents) v0, 3 bytes

```
::n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/38oq7/9/UwA)

### Explanation

```
::    Mode: sequence 2. Given input n, output the sequence n times
  n   Each item in the sequence is n
```

Comment: Note current version uses `&` instead of `::`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 31 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(fill(make-list x)x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXoqDxXyMnMTcpJVGjQlMjLTMnRyM3MTtVF6ikRKFCs0JT8785EAMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 9 bytes

```perl6
{$_ xx$_}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWV5qblFqkW5RakJpYomD7v1olXqGiQiW@9n9xYqUCqqzpfwA)

Uses the built-in list/statement repeat operator `xx`

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 22 bytes

```
{n:Int->(1..n).map{n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@8/1P600TyE3MTNPI7EovdhKwbGoKLHSJrikKDMv3U5ToZpLAQgKgLySnDyN6jwrz7wSXTsNQz29PE293MSC6rzaWg1TTU2u2v//TQE)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 9 bytes

```
_2:'[2:`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/P97ISj3ayCoh9v9/UwA)

```
_        input 
2:       double the input 
'        push one to control stack
[2:`]    for (number), double it, output one of them
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 10 characters

```ruby
->n{[n]*n}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->n{[n]*n}[5]
=> [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmD7X9curzo6L1Yrr/Z/gUJatGnsfwA)

#### Ruby, 18 characters

```ruby
->n{Array.new n,n}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->n{Array.new n,n}[5]
=> [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmD7X9cur9qxqCixUi8vtVwhTyev9n@BQlq0aex/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
{@($_)*$_}
```

### Usage

```
PS C:\> 2 | % {@($_)*$_}
2
2
```

And:

```
PS C:\> 5 | % {@($_)*$_}
5
5
5
5
5
```

By default, PowerShell shows array content one element per line. Running it through the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet shows it in a more familiar form:

```
PS C:\> 5 | % {@($_)*$_} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
[5,5,5,5,5]
```

Comment: Can you call this with `5 | % {@($_)*$_}`?  If so you don't need the 3 bytes (`$f=`) required to name the function.

Comment: Yes it can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## TI Basic, 10 [bytes](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens)

This assumes an empty list

```
Ans→dim(L₁:L₁+Ans
```

Here's the hex, along with the code to explain the byte count:

```
72  04 B5   5D 00 3E 5D 00 70 71
Ans →  dim( L₁    :  L₁    +  Ans
```

### How?

```
Ans→dim(L₁:L₁+Ans
Ans→dim(L₁        Since the list is empty, this makes L₁ a list on Ans 0's
          :       Separator
           L₁+Ans Since TI-Basic vectorizes some commands,
                  this adds Ans (basically the input here) to each element in L₁,
                  which results in Ans for each element.
```

Comment: `Ans+0rand(Ans` for 5 bytes

Comment: Thanks, I'll post that in another solution, since it's pretty different!

Comment: Actually, that's six bytes, `rand(` isn't a thing. It's `Ans` `+` `0` `rand` `(` `Ans`.

Comment: You're right. Instincts..

Comment: Also should mention that on newer calculators (CSE?) you can use `ceiling()` to save a byte

Answer (score 2):

## TI Basic, 6 bytes

```
Ans+0rand(Ans
```

Thanks to @Oki for this solution!

Comment: `0` can be replaced with lots of things (`int(`/`iPart(`, `imag(`, `angle(`, ...). Alternative solution: `Ansnot(not(rand(Ans`. Other noteworthy solutions  (1 byte longer) `randInt(Ans,Ans,Ans`, `Ansrand(Ans)^0`, `Ans(1^rand(Ans`, `-Ansint(-rand(Ans`

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 12 bytes

```
({}){({})}{}
```

#### Run example

```
$ ./flurry -inn -c "({}){({})}{}" 3
3 3 3
$ ./flurry -inn -c "({}){({})}{}" 6
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

This uses the "push x y times" construct `y {({})} x`, just that in this case both are the input number `n`.

```
({})  Pop and push n; evaluates to n
{({})}  A lambda that returns its argument unchanged,
        pushing its argument once onto the stack
{}    Pop n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 4 bytes

```
*aAa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9fK9ERSFoAAA)

## Explanation:

```
*a  : Multiply a times(Here, 8) [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8] 
  A : List-ify a [8]
   a: All a's will be assigned with the first input argument) 8
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>9</s> <s>5</s> <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
Ｅθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUCjUEehUFPT@v//aNPY/7plOQA)

-4 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil), -1 byte thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

### Explanation

```
Ｅ  Ｉθ Map with lambda returning first input cast to integer
  Ｎ    Implicit range over next (first) input
```

Comment: Ah, `×` vectorises these days, so to get list repetition, you need to embed it in a list?

Comment: Yeah, not sure if it's the best idea :/ but someone said so

Comment: Never mind, `ＮθＥθθ` is shorter even with non-vectorising `×`.

Comment: Damnit lol [I had this in mind](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ0zqgKDOvRMM3PydFI7owVqdQU/P/f9P/umX/dYtzAA), do you want to post a separate answer?

Comment: Ah, `Mold` still works, that's good to know!

Comment: Old McDonald had an integer list, `ＥＩθＩθ`... well, almost! Would `ＥＩθθ` be a valid answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no :P the OP states that "The elements need to be integers, not strings."

Comment: [Save a byte](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0fBObG4RKNQU1PT@v9/0/@6Zf91i3MA) by using `Ｎ`.

Comment: Oh yeah oops lol will do when I get back on a computer

Comment: Surely this isn't 35 bytes. I don't know Charcoal, but I'd guess it's in a format such that it's 4, right?

Comment: @cole Oops lol copied directly from TIO, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
DÄWî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/f5XBL@OF1//@bAgA)

```
DÄWî

D     duplicate
 Ä    push n onto the stack n times
  W   wrap the stack in a list
   î  cast to integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 3 bytes

```
]1*
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5D1%2a&input=5&warnings=0)**

```
]1  - Wrap the input into a list.
  * - Repeat the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
#~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/v8LWSrkOSCmYAgA)

`#` copy

`~` self

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
n->[n|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y46r6bCRjfaUE8vLzb2f1p@kUYeUMZAR8FUR6GgKDOvBMhXUtC1AxJpGnmampr/AQ)

Or:

```
n->vector(n,x,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P164sNbkkv0gjT6dCJ0/zfxqICZQx0FEw1VEoKMrMKwHylRR07YBEmkaepqbmfwA)

Or:

```
n->powers(1,n,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P164gvzy1qFjDUCdPJ0/zf1p@kUYeUMZAR8FUR6GgKDOvBMhXUtC1AxJpGnmampr/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 6 bytes

```
[:rep]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9qqKLUg9r@DVRpXdJoCkF0UqwDkFHBFqztkpijo2ik4pBWoKyrkl5aAJEpSi0u4uAwUwLQxhDKFUBZg6j8A)

This is an anonymous function that takes input on the stack and leaves output on the stack. This simply takes the input, duplicates it, then repeats the input by the input.

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic 4.5, 48 bytes

```
INPUT a
DIM t(a)
FOR x=1TO a
t(x)=a
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 3 bytes

Assumes the integer is on the stack already.

```
d×
```

This just duplicates the top stack element and then performs stack multiplication (i.e. Python's `[x]*y`).

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
∙r
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjE5cg__,inputs=NQ__)
Outputs to the stack.
Explanation:

```
∙   multiply POP (string, defaults to input) by POP (number, defaults to the same input)
     vertically - so to an array of strings
 r  swap types - convert the strings to numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>28</s>, 22 bytes

```
{(({}[()])<>[]())<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDo7o2WkMzVtPGLjpWQxNI1drY/f9vAgA)

Normally, the version that uses one stack would be shorter. However, in this case it's 6 bytes longer:

```
(({})){({}<(({}))>[()])}{}{}
```

Comment: [One stack in 24 bytes.](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0OjulZTs7q6VgPCio6OjdWsra79/98UAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
w×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/v/zw9P//LQA)

```
w   Wrap input into list
 ×  Repeat (input) times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 6 bytes

```
ωi×ω+↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//98Z@bh6ec7tR@1bf3//78pAA)

### How?

- `ω`, push the first command line argument evaluated
- `i`, pop `n`; push `[1...n]`
- `×`, pop `a`; pop `b`; push `b*a`. `0` is popped when there is nothing on the stack. Since commands vectorize ("vecify" in MY), it ends up being an array of `n` 0's.
- `ω`, push the first command line argument evaluated
- `+`, pop `a`; pop `b`; push `b+a`. Adds the command line argument to every item in the array of `0` repeated `n` times, giving us `n` repeated `n` times
- `↵`, pop `n`; print `n` with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 33 bytes

```
X*L:-maplist(=(X),L),length(L,X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0LLx0o3N7EgJ7O4RMNWI0JTx0dTJyc1L70kQ8NHJ0JT7/9/Uy0fPQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 22 bytes

```
time {lappend L $n} $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@V@cWqKQp2D6vyQzN1WhOiexoCA1L0XBR0ElrxaI/xeUlhQrqPj8BwA)

---

With built-ins:

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 13 bytes

```
lrepeat $n $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@V@cWqKQp2DKxVVQWlKsEP0/pyi1IDWxREElD4j@x/4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## MacOS bash, 12

```bash
jot $1 $1 $1
```

This also works on Linux if the `jot` package is installed, e.g. `sudo apt install athena-jot`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pyu/REHFEIL@//9vCgA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
;α
```

Explanation:

```
;α
;   duplicate the input
 α  push a list containing n copies of n
```

`α` is not a builtin for this challenge by the usual definition, because it does not solve this challenge by itself. `α` takes the top stack element (call it `a`) and repeats the next stack element (`b`) `a` times. It's roughly equivalent to iterable multiplication in Python (`[5, 1]*2 == [5, 5, 1, 1]`), but also works on non-iterables (`52α` yields `[5, 5]`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/63Mb//00B)

Answer (score 1):

## 4, 32 bytes

```
3.700001000260201801500101010294
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jP3AAIDIHYyMzAyMDQwsDQFMQHQSNLk///lQE)

If you have concerns regarding the input format, please [read this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/65326) first.

**Transpiles roughly as**

```
grid[1] = grid[0] = input()
while grid[1] != 0:
  print(grid[0])
  grid[1] -= 1
```

Comment: this can only handle single-digit numbers properly

Comment: @TimothyGroote no; read the meta post. this handles numbers as bytes, because that's the main form of input for that language. input `1` is 48, and will print `1` (byte representation) 48 times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/braingolf), 6 bytes

```
!A.$_=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9f0VFPJd72////5gA)

### Explanation

```
!A.$_=  Implicit input from commandline args
!A      Read top of stack without popping, run next operator that many times
  .     Duplicate top of stack
   $_   Pop top of stack
     =  Print stack
```

We have to pop the top of the stack because otherwise we'll have 1 too many copies of `n`. If we remove the `!` and let `A` pop the top of the stack, duplicate will have nothing to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 13 bytes

```
#(repeat % %)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/documentation), 68 bytes

```
fun n=>(fix f k n:=match n with|0=>nil|S n=>(k::f k n)%list end) n n
```

Of course there's a library function, giving 46 bytes:

```
Require List. Definition f n:=List.repeat n n.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found this lang and wanted to give it a go.

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 164 bytes

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A CHZBRGR
GIMMEH CHZBRGR
CHZBRGR IS NOW A NUMBR
IM IN YR CRIB UPPIN YR HMBRGR TIL BOTH SAEM CHZBRGR AN HMBRGR
VISIBLE CHZBRGR
IM OUTTA YR CRIB
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LCsJAEET3c4o6gaDgAbrDkG5MT8J81LhVd4HcfzUJmmRVFPV4Nc3Te/58axVSnE8XpxBKIDTy4thG16qZl6NuCU0I/WPlQjGOTg0aMEY0URllGP5N7Adn7cB9FiTytqtAYdvdXZNy54@T1daXnGkXuluWJ4@@1usC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đ⑴*
```

Explanation:

```
                Implicit input
Đ               Duplicates input
 ⑴             Pushes an array, [1,1,...,1], with input 1's, onto the stack
   *            Multiply the array element-wise by the input
                Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHE7do/f9vCgA)

Answer (score 1):

## **FORTH 21 Bytes**

```
: B 0 DO DUP . LOOP ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
10 B
10 B 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
:MR:B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvhv6Oju6Wrt7pITVPffyjfIyun/f0MuIy5jLhMuUwA)

#### Example full program & How it works

```
1AGIE;GDlR~
:MR:B

1AG          Register row 1 as function G
   IE;       Take number input; halt on EOF
      G      Call G
       D     Print the stack contents
        lR~  Empty the stack
             Repeat indefinitely

:M           Duplicate top and decrement
  R:         Duplicate n-1 times
    B        Return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 13 bytes

```
%@!1A[1A~!~]%
```

-15 bytes after integer input rework (Dion).

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%40!1A%5B1A%7E!%7E%5D%25&input=7)

Comment: This input change really effects a lot of answers... 13 bytes https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%40!1A%5B1A~!~%5D%25&input=7

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 6 Bytes

Outputs the list as individual stack elements joined by the newline.

<sup>If built-ins weren't banned, it would be possible via [`♫` (1 bytes)](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=Dg&input=NQ).</sup>

```
◙v◙♦▼e
```

[Try it!](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=CnYKBB9l&input=1%0A%0A2%0A%0A3%0A%0A4%0A%0A5)

### Explanation

```
◙      Duplicate input, in order to get around the edge case 1
 v◙    "◙": Create a copy of the operand, when evaluated
   ♦   Swap up a copy of the input
    ▼  Decrement
     e Repeat input-1 times: Duplicate stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 5 bytes

```
:(|:.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fSqPGSu//f1MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [7 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
|ÅF└¾c)
```

## Explanation

Unpacked: `v{_}\1=>`

```
    \ Fold/map (in this case just map) with...
v{ A block with the key of v
  _ Input
}
      1=> Range, [1, in]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 3], <s>55</s> 49 bytes

```swift
func a(n:Int)->[Int] {return (0..<n).map{_ in n}}
```

Comment: `$0+n-$0` can be replaced by `_ in n` for -1 bytes. Additionally, you can `print` rather than `return` and `->[Int]` to save tons of bytes. You can also remove `Array` and the space before it. This ends up being 41 bytes: `func a(n:Int){print((0..<n).map{_ in n})}`

Comment: Didn't realise you didn't need the `Array` there and interesting how the `_ in n` works, would never have thought of that. However, the challenge says to "return a list", which to me would suggest you need to return something, not just print it, but that may just be my interpretation. I've updated with the other suggestions though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <s>86</s> <s>56</s> 45 bytes

*Thanks to @ceilingcat for saving <s>30</s> 41 bytes!*

```
#import<list>
#define f(n)std::list<int>(n,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU69DoIwEN7vKS6wtFEHTVxo4UlcSFtME7gSergYnh1LjRLjDTd8/2YcT3dj1rX0wxgm1r2P3EBpXefJYSdIRrZVtcHaEzeCjiSTmkw/W4fah8iTa4cG4BG8RXaRRRIiSXgCpvv1ZwHWOVllvgsTvh1YZVZm@Gs1YWbUOtHpFVgo@KOKGyV4AdhihtaT@JTv4fVZIen6clV4ONDekQdvW5b1BQ)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 24 bytes

```
arg n
say copies(n' ',n)
```

Uses the built-in function `copies()`, and naturally, this being REXX, the copies are integers just as much as they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 10 bytes

```
#:(x)[x]*x

(#:(x)[x]*x)(5) // => [5,5,5,5,5]
```

[Try it online!](http://felixguo.me/#wendyScript)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
Du@"Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36XUQelwy///pgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

Super simple

```
.[QQY
```

Explanation:

```
.[QQY     Pad Y with eval(input) copies of eval(input)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy86MDDy/39TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

**Code**

```
>r a:new ( r@ a:push ) r@ times rdrop
```

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `n -- a`

**Usage**

```
: f >r a:new ( r@ a:push ) r@ times rdrop ;

ok> 5 f .
[5,5,5,5,5]
```

We could save another 6 bytes if we accept the idea of leaving numbers on `r-stack` after processing.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 7 bytes

```r
0*1:n+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZ2vx30DL0CpPO@//fwA)

Comment: This isn't a function nor a full program. You have to handle input and output: `function(n)0*1:n+n`, or `cat(0*1:(n=scan())+n)`

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 75 Bytes

Defined `Function` that takes input `n` of expected type `Integer` and returns an array of length `n` filled with `n` to STDOUT

```vb
Function l(n)
Dim o
ReDim o(1To n)
For i=1To n
o(i)=n
Next
l=o
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 49 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs a array of range values, `o`, with bounds `(1 To [A1], 1)` to the VBE immediate window.

```vba
[A1].Resize([A1],1)=[A1]:o=Sheet1.UsedRange.Value
```

Comment: Imo, if your language has no lists, use the next closest thing.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 12

```
~x=fill(x,x)
```

Also it kinda generalizes to tuples making tensors.

```
julia> ~3
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
 3

julia> ~tuple(2,4)
2×4 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (2, 4)  (2, 4)  (2, 4)  (2, 4)
 (2, 4)  (2, 4)  (2, 4)  (2, 4)

julia> ~tuple(2,4,3)
2×4×3 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)

[:, :, 2] =
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)

[:, :, 3] =
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)
 (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)  (2, 4, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 12 bytes

```
Ans→dim(L₁:Ans(L₁+1
```

Assumes an empty list.

Comment: No, `Ans`, `→`, & `dim(`, 1 byte, `L₁`, 2 bytes, `:`, `Ans`, & `(`, 1 byte, `L₁`, 2 bytes, `+` & `1`, 1 byte.

Comment: Whoops, thought `Ans(` was all one byte, derp.

Answer (score 0):

## [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) 107 Bytes

```
#define a NSMutableArray
-(a*)f:(int)n{a*m=[a arrayWithCapacity:n];for(int i=0;i<n;i++)m[i]=@(n);return m;}
```

A little macro abuse and a basic loop, everyone else took the good languages...

### Usage

```
[self f:5];
```

returns an array of number objects of the given value

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript II, 14 bytes

```
$s{o`s`+s}sNv*
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
ns[>l<1-]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@vONoux8ZQN9bu/38jAA)

Prints space-separated numbers. If outputting without a separator is allowed, `ns[lu1-];` works for 9 bytes.

Explanation:

```
ns[>l<1-]>

ns         # take input and save it
  [        # loop
   >l<     # load save and push it to another stack
      1-   # decrement
        ]  # end loop
         > # go to other stack
           # implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 32 bytes

```
let m n=List.map(fun x->n)[1..n]
```

Creates a list 1 to n, then mapping a function to each element to replace it with n.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 23 bytes

```
f(x)==[x for i in 1..x]
```

This 15 bytes would be better

```
f(x)⊳[x|i∈1..x]
```

f(x) return the list contains x element x
but Axiom is a good approximation to that.
Goes under 15 bytes it seems too much golfed

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 12 bytes

```
->(n){[n]*n}
```

13 bytes

```
Array.new n,n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
dim g(:)[a|g(b)=a
```

This is a direct port of my QBasic answer (48 bytes), and QBIC does what it does best: compressing QBasic.

### Explanation

```
dim g(:) Defines an array of x elements, where x is a cmd line param
[a|      FOR b = 1 TO a (the : above creates 'a' and assigns the cmd line param to it)
g(b)=a   Set each array element to 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), 21

```dc
?dsn[lnpr1-d0!=F]dsFx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@pTgvOievoMhQN8VA0dYtNqXYreL/f1MA)

Ungolfed:

```dc
# Read a number from standard input (?), save it to register n (sn) and leave a copy on the stack (d)
?dsn

# Function F: print register n as many times as the top of the stack shows
[            # start of macro
  lnp        # print register n
  r          # swap the counter to the top
  1-         # decrement counter
  d          # duplicate counter for the comparison
  0 !=F      # if counter is not zero run F again
]dsFx        # end of macro, save it to F (sF) and execute (d x)
```

Run on the command line like this:

```
echo 5 | dc dcscript
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

This shorter script works for `n>1` (15 bytes):

```
? [d d z 1- <F]dsFx f
```

This uses the depth of the stack to determine when to stop.

Comment: This only prints *n* *n* times, it doesn't create a list or array containing *n* copies of *n* which is what the challenge asks for, unfortunately this not a valid solution.

Comment: @BMO: converting to a list is trivial: `echo -n '['; echo 5 | dc dcscript | paste -sd, | tr -d \\n ; echo ']'`

Comment: That would make it a `bash` submission though.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 26 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input, `n` from range `[A1]` and returns an array object `X` with `n` stuffed into it `n` times.

```vb
x=Split([Rept(A1&" ",A1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 41 bytes

```
R	R =ARRAY(N,N)	:(RETURN)
	DEFINE('R(N)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCoAgEADQ@fwKN@@gMQgiA0EDlzMOBVubI4f@H3N7vO9td3vmDit66gKirRNxF/LENFJCLsKkPPhwRA5oBJkMdajaRj5LVpC0Faw0UPIIbdNWdxXY9@UH)

`ARRAY` initializes an array with the given indices, in this case, `1:N`. It has an optional argument which it uses to initialize all the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 23 bytes

```
/i///0./.1//1/i,//.//i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz9TX1/fQE9fz1Bf31A/U0dfX09fP1Pv/38A)

Since there is no other way to take input in ///, it is hard coded. Also, since /// is a string-based language, input is in unary.

Example with input 5:

```
/i/00000//0./.1//1/i,//.//i.
```

How it works (with example input 5):

```
/i/00000//0./.1//1/i,//.//i.    Program with input.
/i/00000/                       Replace i with input. This is to make 1 uniform input.
         /0./.1/                Replace "0." with ".1". This turns all the 0s to 1s in the later i without bothering the next piece of code.
                /1/i,/          Replace 1s with input and a comma. This places the input into where the 1s were, essentially replacing each unary char of the input with the input, delimited with commas.
                      /.//      Remove the period.
                          i.    Input with period, main thing being modified by code.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <del>63</del> 54 Bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Xcoder

```
a=[];i=input()
for _ in" "*int(i):a+=(i);
print(a)
```

**Same code but will print every iteration of the list, saves 2 bytes**

```
a=[];i=input()
for _ in" "*int(i):a+=(i);print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, although I am still trying to figure out how I could get rid of the variables I needed to set

Comment: You should post that as your answer, not going to copy it.

Comment: That's up to you :) However I already have [my own answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139826/59487).

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 45 bytes

```
SUBROUTINE B(I)
INTEGER A(I)
A=I
PRINT*,A
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8PcnV00dLx5HJ29PFRcNLw1ORy9XPhCg51CvIPDfH0c4WIefqFuLq7Bik4gjiOtp5cAUFAIS0dR5Dq//9NAQ)

This is a simple version, in which the subroutine is used to avoid the allocation stuff, since we have a unknown length array. The TIO link leads to a version with the full program, with 67 bytes in total.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 4 bytes

**Solution:**

```
x#x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v0K5wsr0/38A)

**Explanation:**

`5#5` means take from 5, 5 times. But doesn't appear we can do the same trick as APL/J to reduce this one down.

```
x#x: / the solution
  x: / save input as x
x#   / take from it x times
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
]x*
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5Dx*&i=5%0A65&m=2)

Internally it actually converts an integer to the array required but the implicit output changes it to codepoints. By default, output by codepoint is allowed though.

### Explanation

```
]      Convert input to singleton
 x*    Repeat input times
```

Comment: `y*` does it without using the codepoint exemption. `y` is the first line of standard input by default.

Comment: True, but "The elements need to be integers, not strings".

Answer (score 0):

## 12-basic, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
?[X=INPUT()]*X
```

[Try](https://12me21.github.io/12-basic/#Ttextarea%3B%3F%5BX%3DINPUT()%5D*X~T%23%5C%24input%3B5~Cbutton)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 15 bytes

Shorter Kotlin answer using the `List` constructor.

```
{n->List(n){n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsJADED3fkW6JYNuLsUWHIVufkHAXgmeOUlTQY779vMQfOt7vEfyKFrDrvBkUWRbtwEuZvw539xE14kgd9B4c4QAY806XNUP0yybo1LWUurfJxghoC18n0UXpL4/emo1Ev0er3b0qJioK/X0BQ)

Ungolfed:

```
// lambda function
{ n ->
    List(n) { n }  // create a List of n Ints where each item is n
}
```

Because `List` is actually an `interface`, `List()` is actually a function that creates a `List` of the specified type (here figured out through inference) and a fixed size, using the given lambda to initialize the value of each item. `{ n }` means the lambda will always return the value of `n`.

Comment: [15](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwFEX3fsXt9t5QN5fSBhyFbn5BwKYE44ukT0FCvj1Gwbud4Zx7ixq8VPcU3K0XsmnbR5xSsu/posnLZhi5Q9vLBjiMoLMoYzBY/K5TA4O5ZhnMl0k4Syn1L0TMcJRWe128rMR9f9DYHGL@RR/tQoNQ5K7U4wc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-m`, 1 byte

```
N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@//f1MuLt1cAA)

`-m` is a flag that runs the program on each item in the input. Because the input is a number, it gets turned into a range first. `N` is the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 7 bytes

```
I:R:~D;
```

This uses the convenient 'D' - Debug operator, which outputs the stack!

```
I       //Get integer input
 :R:    //Repeat input, double the number
    ~D; //Delete the last item in the stack(to get the right number) and output the entire stack with debug
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MqyKrOxfr/f2MA)

Comment: lol, there's already a 5 byte one

Comment: @ASCII-only I didn't see that... Well, at the very least mine doesn't use a header, it does it on its own

Comment: Yeah well that's just the difference between a function and a program :P

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 83 bytes

Rockstar only has string I/O so output is a comma delimited string, which may not be allowed by the spec. To conform with the spec, though, the second line ensures the elements in the actual array are integers.

```
listen to N
cast N
X's0
while N-X
let L at X be N
let X be+1

join L with ","
say L
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bound](https://github.com/HoofedEar/Bound), 6 bytes

```
ic1-Rc
```

Explaination:

```
i # Get input (for example 5) [5]
c # Copy the top element [5, 5]
1 # Put 1 onto the stack [5, 5, 1]
- # Subtraction [5, 4]
R # Pop the top element, repeat the next command that many times [5]
c # Copy the top element [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VrrdhM3EP7tfQrFNI1NHBOH0ovb0EK5NOe00AOUntOQ@shrOVaRV1tJ60tvD9UH6SulM5L25l1MggkQ/4mjy8w3o9Hc5HhpJjK6eXbGp7FUhrg/gg8DP6CXOv16KmQ2PKVmkn5XNBrJaTBWckqk7sYw5emQ3ySPOkOqWUSnrKNjwQ1bmCB4fv/J06PHj8ghac72uwfdXjOIkqng2uDQfu/g5ie3Pv3s8y@aQTBiY@DGo1bY7geNEObDrmKxoCFrNUmzQ5rNdtDQMlEhg8njcEIVGUtF7BcekfCkMI0sWorNmNJs1HLDbdgvWHQKsGEBi9LhoDEDCodkZwcIGBq@RPInQdCYT7hgxG/ZOiT7AKxh1BL/NMJEKRahHI5MN5ZxC2g12CJksSFH0Ygt7isllV0@VIy@BJoNPibZVuDZ3emTa@RxYuIEDgG54@pY8ci07L/tmk27dtOd0YgbLiPcAAusRHYHuX1IDixXHOeaRzAegR7t9PFe76QDCjNtAgdaM33gpx2FTGD4UJQWF2XC4mdYO@pGaByzaNQakl1C/YzXz7NlzHL1oEJlZHiUsBp596y8T5OhUTS8MiLvbSLydSvyD4kwHG5TSK@M1NfPL/Va3NqojXGDBs2EIal6Cfw80NpYluoJbrsTlKNEyCtxctubSHvDSnuPz/iIdYiSCeBO4isgN0a4bsi4AA3cAA1cxHjTVb8wJVF0DZf0vAp78aJGYyM5v7xbTt6y0sZCSvWOtfarVdqPcs7U1fCGG7mQay7u/Z5QxWrF7Z1D3PPKU0JOEfnBmyO/bZE/hKTHMAVOln6gwQs4wyndhkNKd5f10EsXMqFZ/ZL9N9fSV1ZL3zOtP3gVffWeVHRoVXQUGXYKhvStnMZUcS0/aF0B7vejrL9cXTDUUiSGkRkVybv2G0PdOn80qEqwZSV4AFm@VJyKdwveRbWU90ZynPo4FVtz03SGWSYciFonkStDiyCrhB9awk9cYUwMMLCnTOYcalQkgPxCwdZzgnFcu4VFr5emopuSamC1H85q5Sq2L124mtPYAjNzSZhgU5jW665rdjJ4fEHpcuG9DDIwOA8zw@LIAY7QGjAdr6ipBN1TIcgQCmyAtQ5JWv3b7sGUxi0wJVuJ5ObVbtedyjeeme035GX8q/iUGeVtCruujv5Hlr7GVosraC7EAPetJT@y5E2iIkseD497jwt/JaG2ybLpZSwZVDjxSnUmVwvrxY7F9QzguCaPJnDlQFkgDYBM67YLY8LS0mOq9QoloFKNrCeowtMW3c@Kg6uVzrhSe98Ull7qrjYjoNqdI/2C/QUr0aNmaclcYVUV@lPnnrDLpB12f@xvCX@hf1ULOp0vI63i/NPdK2kgjSziw9NHyIKN12JNr4Hj0uufkF3/vd87qeH392v4KX46uQDDvRLHvVqWP636qTEVernecRaZHffRAx4vbC90gVHGYYBNC9u0rGP6JI0ikJ9bwSK2MHC5plMMHwwKDpGKnIeYTe9/7V1D1ANE7VwhjU4ZFB97pNfOMqhCEPcN3vRuuv9yC4NPfYO3GMZXGrPlQF5VVd@qChLPIY@YzlRSDG6oaxhfEijTUsepr0B5mt7BYdsaqUI/9@YpT@h8CjgTCBcyXhI5vohbKSEreI4qo49TRjo/Afso0UObjToEwItE8xkTS9Jii/jOo3u6fSnWC8Rh2Fltr0Pobq9g1jwza1iWWXP5BOrk@8ddTvvawv9gecQnQop1ZuUeaLp6kozHgr36@SDKFWhpJ1M8K/Q9Lh5Er0kyvNYMuEkB4u8HJYntOi9tWbG8pFC/f/eQ8JLrrHVlkTRFSgtH6aRqOZZondBHvpAMlffo3jS9lTpOl2IkK42VXfBtNfjuuXYge@/40PfiRBXi184VTpg7k1qEkKNBOhtdClCsrinZJgeIZr/@RqUXsFhfr5bXVcmGVrK7@EanCY2pMsVE2CXBmsUK04K1Dv5thMPcb5RKEHTO53ciLddakiBBAi5bkMtxgPggh5f2mUqbu6dKJrF/TcWPHI81M5mbWJGw8kTbzzsplnYWoxGiLVjbO9mYZ5a5kAI/GOulY6VeSwb5AeRZNo5VQVl/vt8hjlZB7eWX3mwEuWWSOEx537c2I6ke2CB903X5WDIdQvUFVytPMgpuWafZ2WuddMlS8hV1CLjr2TLLC5@jMShEqb0H3gTslBM/y0EqWYVvnfgs4jmmj4U04hVJBAjofxxgl1WI@nUWuysg2sHKS3kA5AYD/BHCYIAyNQcD/E3BYNDsp0ubh3ftU8u2PmyCL/G/UABKqQahnqLqdNbG/VaJ7mcAaOH9/G3eyhfKEctU0vzvX9JMb5mbAQBswU3Tie1@ArAy7@c8tu@YELJD5lKJ0ZYjlhuv@3UEbITxdNQjSEEf2wZKvvDs7NYZD3t7T8L/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes

```
~.])*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v04vVlPr/39TAA)

```
~       # Parse the input to an integer     5
 .      # Copy it                           5 5
  ]     # Put everything in an array       [5 5]
   )    # Remove the last element          [5] 5
    *   # Multiply                         [5 5 5 5 5]
```